# How to create a dictionary from a line of text?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a generated file with thousands of lines like the following:

`CODE,XXX,DATE,20101201,TIME,070400,CONDITION_CODES,LTXT,PRICE,999.0000,QUANTITY,100,TSN,1510000001`

Some lines have more fields and others have fewer, but all follow the same pattern of key-value pairs and each line has a TSN field.

When doing some analysis on the file, I wrote a loop like the following to read the file into a dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv

records = {}
for line in open(argv[1]):
    fields = line.strip().split(',')
    record = dict(zip(fields[::2], fields[1::2]))
    records[record['TSN']] = record

print 'Found %d records in the file.' % len(records)
```

...which is fine and does exactly what I want it to (the `print` is just a trivial example).

However, it doesn't feel particularly "pythonic" to me and the line with:

```
dict(zip(fields[::2], fields[1::2]))
```

Which just feels "clunky" (how many times does it iterate over the fields?).

Is there a better way of doing this in Python 2.6 with just the standard modules to hand?

Comment: I think this is as pythonic as it can get.

Comment: Are you only interested in TSN records? Or do you intend on expanding this to all record types?

Comment: For anyone looking at this question, I've commented in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list) that the walrus operator can now be used (3.8+) to do this in a concise way: `for i, k in zip(_x := iter(mylist), _x): ...`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Python 2 you could use `izip` in the `itertools` module and the magic of generator objects to write your own function to simplify the creation of pairs of values for the `dict` records. I got the idea for `pairwise()` from a similarly named (although functionally different) [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the Python 2 `itertools` docs.

To use the approach in Python 3, you can just use plain `zip()` since it does what `izip()` did in Python 2 resulting in the latter's removal from `itertools` — the example below addresses this and should work in both versions.

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a)
```

Which can be used like this in your file reading `for` loop:

```
from sys import argv

records = {}
for line in open(argv[1]):
    fields = (field.strip() for field in line.split(','))  # generator expr
    record = dict(pairwise(fields))
    records[record['TSN']] = record

print('Found %d records in the file.' % len(records))
```

**But wait, there's more!**

It's possible to create a generalized version I'll call `grouper()`, which again corresponds to a similarly named `itertools` recipe (which is listed right below `pairwise()`):

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ..."
    return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
```

Which could be used like this in your `for` loop:

```
    record = dict(grouper(2, fields))
```

Of course, for specific cases like this, it's easy to use `functools.partial()` and create a similar `pairwise()` function with it (which will work in both Python 2 & 3):

```
import functools
pairwise = functools.partial(grouper, 2)
```

**Postscript**

Unless there's a really huge number of fields, you could instead create a actual sequence out of the pairs of line items (rather than using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which has no `len()`):

```
fields = tuple(field.strip() for field in line.split(','))
```

The advantage being that it would allow the grouping to be done using simple slicing:

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:  # Python 3
    xrange = range

def grouper(n, sequence):
    for i in xrange(0, len(sequence), n):
        yield sequence[i:i+n]

pairwise = functools.partial(grouper, 2)
```

Comment: Many thanks. All of the answers provided were excellent, but your code was the fastest when run over a 2.2 Gb file (even faster than the itertools version) and is easy to read and unit-test. I'm kicking myself for not thinking to look at itertools, there's so much good stuff in there.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Excellent news about the performance. I'm kind of proud of this one, and was already pleased just to have finally determined a fairly elegant way to do this as it is something I frequently find a need for in my own day-to-day Python code.

Comment: Inline `pairwise()` in modern Python: `for i, k in zip(_x := iter(mylist), _x): ...` (using the walrus operator from Python 3.8+).

Answer (score 6):

Not so much better as just [more efficient...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631189/python-every-other-element-idiom/2631256#2631256)

[Full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Comment: The trick here is using list multiplication and `*args` "dereferencing" to ensure that the same object is passed for both parameters to `zip`, so that the iterator state is shared and advanced twice each time `zip` creates a new output tuple. We can do this a few other ways: `x = iter(l); zip(x, x)` is perhaps more readable; `(lambda x: zip(x, x))(iter(l))` perhaps more familiar for the functional-programming folks, although this way is almost designed to pretend we're programming without side effects when in fact we're completely dependent on one ;)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: instead of `(lambda x: zip(x, x))(iter(x))` one could use `(lambda x=iter(x): zip(x, x))()` which is arguably slightly more readable although still dependent on a [different] side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

record = dict(grouper(2, line.strip().split(","))
```

[source](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it's too late for me to undo my up-vote for this after discovering that it's just a verbatim copy of one of the [recipes](http://docs.python.org/librar/itertools.html?highlight=grouper#recipes) in the `itertools` docs -- or what I would have to call plagiarized since no reference or citation is given.

Comment: @martineau: He does have a tiny little link labeled "source" below it.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Oh...obviously I missed that -- sorry @robert -- still don't think it deserves an up-vote though.

Answer (score 1):

If we're going to abstract it into a function anyway, it's not too hard to write "from scratch":

```
def pairs(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try: yield (iterator.next(), iterator.next())
        except: return
```

robert's recipe version definitely wins points for flexibility, though.

Comment: FWIW, it's not "robert's recipe", see my comment under his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/creating-a-python-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text/4356368#4356368).