# Error when using a string as a parameter

Tags: python, string, arguments

I have a list of floats `[234, 533, 734, 964, 623, 744, 244, 353, 264]`. Then, I format it to a string like `"(234, 533, 734), (964, 623, 744), (244, 353, 264)"`.

This is a format example of the function I'm passing it to:

```
cmds.curve( p=[(0, 0, 0), (3, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (9, 9, 9)] )
```

Here's what I used that returned an error:

```
cmds.curve( p = [ pStr ] )
```

Here's the error:

> Line 142: Invalid arguments for flag 'p'.  Expected ( distance, distance, distance ), got [ str, str ] #

Comment: You must change the string to numbers. Is this a python related question? because you could add Python as a tag too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Zaf. I have no idea how to do that. Is my approach the correct way?

Comment: solved it using cmds.curve( p = eval( pStr ) )

Comment: @WarrenDaza, eval is generally frowned upon.

Comment: There was another question similar here on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/python-parse-string-to-float-or-int maybe that help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works for you.  I have a feeling that you are converting to a string unnecessarily.

```
floats = [234, 533, 734, 964, 623, 744, 244, 353, 264]
groups = [tuple(floats[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(floats), 3] 
cmds.curve(p=groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364399/322909), click [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for the python docs.

```
>>> my_list = [234, 533, 734, 964, 623, 744, 244, 353, 264]
>>> zip(*[iter(my_list)]*3)
[(234, 533, 734), (964, 623, 744), (244, 353, 264)]
```

Comment: Heh, this might be too clever :P  Also, what's with the `1:`?

Comment: @askewchan, I used a program called [dreampie](http://www.dreampie.org/) as my python shell, and it puts those number in there.