# How can I join a list of characters into strings of 8?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a python list of chars and want to join them to create a list of strings of 8 elements each, eg:

```
x = ['0','0','1','a','4','b','6','2','2','1','4','1','5','7','9','8']
```

result

```
['001a4b62', '21415798']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) contains a `grouper` recipe that groups consecutive items to fixed-sized groups:

```
from itertools import *

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Now you can just group into lists of size 8, and turn each one to a string:

```
>>> [''.join(e) for e in grouper(x, 8)]
['001a4b62', '21415798']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x = ['0','0','1','a','4','b','6','2','2','1','4','1','5','7','9','8']
```

Simply:

```
print(["".join(x[i:i + 8]) for i in range(0, len(x), 8)])
> ['001a4b62', '21415798']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use join to convert an array of characters to a string.
Here's how you'd do it in your case -

```
x = ['0','0','1','a','4','b','6','2','2','1','4','1','5','7','9','8']
i = 0
strlist = []
while i<len(x):
  strlist.append(''.join(x[i:i+8]))
  i+=8
```

strlist will hold your grouped strings.

Answer (score 1):

First check out the following [How to split python list into chunks of equal size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364391/how-to-split-python-list-into-chunks-of-equal-size)

With this in place you can do in python 3.x, give the above variable `x`

```
import operator
import functools
result = map(lambda s: functools.reduce(operator.add, s), zip(*[iter(x)]*8))
```

In python 2.x you can drop the `functools` prefix for reduce.

fricke