# Getting two-tuples out of a list

Tags: python

I just extracted some data from a list using python but think it's overcomplicated and unpythonic and there's probably a much better way to do this. I'm actually pretty sure I saw this somewhere in the standard library docs but my brain refuses to tell me where.

So here it goes:

Input:

```
x = range(8) # any even sequence
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

My take:

```
[ [x[i], x[i+1]] for i in range(len(x))[::2] ]
```

Comment: You say two-tuples but your examples are "two-lists"

Comment: duplicated (a lot of times): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Comment: Oops, of course, sorry for the mixup. Doesn't really matter for the question though ;)

Comment: I think it does matter. Tuples are a lot simpler than lists, as demonstrated in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007736/getting-two-tuples-out-of-a-list/6007963#6007963).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Tuples?

#### In Python 2.*n*

```
>>> zip(*2*[iter(x)])
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

#### In Python 3.*n*

[`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#zip) behaves slightly differently...

```
>> zip(*2*[iter(x)])
<zip object at 0x285c582c>
>>> list(zip(*2*[iter(x)])])
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

### Lists?

The implementation is the same in Python 2 and 3...

```
>>> [[i,j] for i,j in zip(*2*[iter(x)])]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(*2*[iter(x)])]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

The latter is more useful if you want to split into `list`s of 3 or more elements, without spelling it out, such as:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(*4*[iter(x)])]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

---

If `zip(*2*[iter(x)])` looks a little odd to you (and it did to me the first time I saw it!), take a look at [How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python).

See also [this pairwise implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/creating-a-python-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text/4356415#4356415), which I think is pretty neat.

Comment: This is actually really elegant (but a little hard to read). Thanks for all answers, learned a lot :)

Comment: I find `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` quite ugly, but the idiom is in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), so I guess it's Pythonic. For pairs, I like the `pairwise()` version to which I linked. [Beautiful is better than ugly](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want tuples instead of lists you can try:

```
>>> zip(range(0, 8, 2), range(1, 8, 2))
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
x = range(8) # any even sequence
```

**Solution:**

```
output = []
for i, j in zip(*[iter(x)]*2):
    output.append( [i, j] )
```

**Output:**

```
print output
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it a bit:

```
>>> l = range(8)
>>> [[l[i], l[i+1]] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 2)]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

For some list tasks you can use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), but I'm pretty sure there's no helper function for this one.