# how to convert csv into dict format

Tags: python, csv

I have a.csv file as below:

```
 OLD,NEW
 AA,XX
 BB,YY
 CC,ZZ
```

I wanna convert it to dict format, 
say dict1 = {'AA':'XX','BB':'YY','CC':'ZZ'}
Should I use DictReader or join string?

Comment: Just two columns? Ignoring the first line? I guess [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/creating-a-python-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text) is overkill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    f.readline() # ignore first line (header)
    mydict = dict(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))

print mydict
```

Comment: @MSY: "Thanks [...] it solved my question" is best expressed [by  clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Ok, checked. Appreciate this.