# Fill a list in a loop

Tags: python, list

I'm reading a file of data and i have a list that contains the line of the file and it's like this:

```
>>> oz[:15]
[' 283283283283283283283283284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n',
' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n',
...
' 291291292292292292292292293293293293293293293293293293293293294294294294294\n',
' 294294294294294294294294295295   lat =  -89.5\n']
```

Now I want to store the numbers in this list in a smart way and I need an element list for every 3 digits, but if I print the output in this way everything is ok:

```
for ll in range(0,60):
    for k in range(1,73+3,3):
        if k==31 and ((ll+1)%15==0): 
            break                       
        else: 
            print oz[ll][k:k+3]
```

I got the right output, the numbers 283, 283,... But if I try to store them in a list the result in the list is wrong:

```
DU = []

# Populate DU array
for ll in range(0,2700):
    for k in range(1,73+3,3):
        if k==31 and ((ll+1)%15==0): 
            break                       
        else: 
            DU.append(oz[ll][k:k+3])
```

What am I doing wrong filling the list DU?

EDIT: I explain better what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a list oz that has this format:

```
[' 283283283283283283283283284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283282282283283282282282282283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284285285285285285285285285285285285285285285\n', ' 285285286286286286286286286287287287287287287288288288288288288288288288288\n', ' 288289289289289289289289289290290290290290290290290290291291291291291291291\n', ' 291291292292292292292292293293293293293293293293293293293293294294294294294\n', ' 294294294294294294294294295295   lat =  -89.5\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284283283284284284284284284284284284284284284283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283282282282282282282282282282282282282282281\n', ' 281281281281281281281281281281281281281281281281280280280280280280280280279\n', ' 279279279279279279279279279279279279279279278278278278278278278278278278278\n', ' 277277278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278\n', ' 278278279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279\n', ' 279279280280280280280280280280280280280280280280280280280281281281281281281\n', ' 281282282282282282282282283283283283283283284284284284284284285285285285285\n', ' 286286286287287287287288288288288288288289289289289289290290290290291291291\n', ' 292292292292292292293293293293293293293293293294294294294295295295295295295\n', ' 296296296296296296296297297297   lat =  -88.5\n']
```

What I need is to fill a list with the triplets of number like ['283', '283', '283', '283'] rembembering that every 15 lines there's a line with the "lat..." text that I want to strip.
I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: In what way is the list "wrong"?

Comment: It's not filled with the right numbers while in the "print" output are right. I was wondering if there was something wrong with the use of the .append() method..

Comment: Give an example of the output you want and the output you're getting instead.

Comment: is it an IndexError that you are getting?

Comment: how are you reading in data to get that

Comment: the code looks OK, does it work w/o problems for '60' ? maybe yer data is corrupted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code at the moment seems very hard coded I'm unsure as to what you are trying to achieve but try:

```
DU = []

for index, line in enumerate(oz):

   line = line.strip() if (index +1) % 15 != 0 else line.strip().split(' ')[0]

   for i in range(0,len(line)-3,3):

      DU.append(line[i:i+3])
```

or could you try a combination of the answers

```
 from itertools import izip

 def grouped(iterable, n):
      "s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,s2n+2,...s3n-1), ..."
      return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

 DU = []

 for index, line in enumerate(oz):

        line = line.strip() if (index +1) % 15 != 0 else line.strip().split(' ')[0]


        DU.append(map(''.join, grouped(line.strip(), 3)))
```

Comment: try this. is this what you're after?

Comment: Uhm this has the same output of my code, with this code works with a small number of lines like 30 but if I use 2700 that is the len(oz) it breaks and repeat the same numbers:
`DU = []
for ll in range(0,30):
    for k in range(1,73+3,3):
         if k==31 and ((ll+1)%15==0): 
           break                     
            else: 
             DU.append(oz[ll][k:k+3])
`

Comment: slight edit ok i've tried my code over the input you gave and it works

Comment: With mine and your code I got the same output but it's not right, I don't understand if there's some ordering somewhere.. but the numbers don't match with the original oz list...

Comment: are you sure they don't match you realise the input you gve starts at 283 increases to 284 before going back to 283

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use something along the lines of the update in my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356415/355230) to group the string of digits in each number. Specifically using this code with the number string as the iterable and a value of 3 for the `n` (group-size) argument:

```
from itertools import izip

def grouped(iterable, n):
    "s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,s2n+2,...s3n-1), ..."
    return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

digits = '283283283283283283283283284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n'

print map(''.join, grouped(digits.strip(), 3))
```

Output:

```
['283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '284', '284', 
'284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', 
'284', '284', '284', '284', '284']
```

I note however that the last line of the data in your example, the:

```
'294294294294294294294294295295 lat = -89.5\n'
```

is not simply a string of digits, so it will have to be handled as a special case.

**Update:**

OK, now that I see the additional information you added to your question, I can provide a complete solution for you based on the `grouped()` function from my other answer, as I initially suggested. This handles the special line which occurs periodically in your input data by splitting up each line of data and then ignoring all but the first -- often the only -- item of that, which is always a string of digits which are then further processed via my function.

```
from itertools import izip

def grouped(iterable, n):
    "s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,s2n+2,...s3n-1), ..."
    return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

data = [' 283283283283283283283283284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283282282283283282282282282283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284285285285285285285285285285285285285285285\n', ' 285285286286286286286286286287287287287287287288288288288288288288288288288\n', ' 288289289289289289289289289290290290290290290290290290291291291291291291291\n', ' 291291292292292292292292293293293293293293293293293293293293294294294294294\n', ' 294294294294294294294294295295   lat =  -89.5\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284283283284284284284284284284284284284284284283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283284284284284284284284284284284284284284284284\n', ' 284284284284284284284284284284284284283283283283283283283283283283283283283\n', ' 283283283283283283283283283283283282282282282282282282282282282282282282281\n', ' 281281281281281281281281281281281281281281281281280280280280280280280280279\n', ' 279279279279279279279279279279279279279279278278278278278278278278278278278\n', ' 277277278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278278\n', ' 278278279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279279\n', ' 279279280280280280280280280280280280280280280280280280280281281281281281281\n', ' 281282282282282282282282283283283283283283284284284284284284285285285285285\n', ' 286286286287287287287288288288288288288289289289289289290290290290291291291\n', ' 292292292292292292293293293293293293293293293294294294294295295295295295295\n', ' 296296296296296296296297297297   lat =  -88.5\n']

DU = []
for line in data:
    DU.extend(map(''.join, grouped(line.strip().split()[0], 3)))

print DU
```

Output:

```
['283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '282', '282', '283', '283', '282', '282', '282', '282', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '286', '286', '286', '286', '286', '286', '286', '287', '287', '287', '287', '287', '287', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '289', '289', '289', '289', '289', '289', '289', '289', '290', '290', '290', '290', '290', '290', '290', '290', '290', '291', '291', '291', '291', '291', '291', '291', '291', '291', '292', '292', '292', '292', '292', '292', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '294', '295', '295', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '283', '283', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '277', '277', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '279', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '280', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '281', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '282', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '283', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '284', '285', '285', '285', '285', '285', '286', '286', '286', '287', '287', '287', '287', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '288', '289', '289', '289', '289', '289', '290', '290', '290', '290', '291', '291', '291', '292', '292', '292', '292', '292', '292', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '293', '294', '294', '294', '294', '295', '295', '295', '295', '295', '295', '296', '296', '296', '296', '296', '296', '296', '297', '297', '297']
```

You could make an efficient fairly unreadable list comprehension out of it like this:

```
from itertools import chain

DU = list(chain.from_iterable(map(''.join, grouped(line.strip().split()[0], 3))
                                             for line in data))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions to match sets of 3 consecutive digits:

```
import re

def oz_reader(oz):
    for line in oz:
        matches = re.findall(r"\d{3}", line)
        for num in matches:
            yield num
```

Note, that function returns a generator, rather than a list. If you really need a list with the output, just use the `list` constructor on it:

```
result_list = list(oz_reader(oz))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for the replies, the code was actually working well and I had the problem in another part of my program, I was just tired but thank you for the different possibilities you gave for this code!