# How to check if a sequence of INTs are in a list and remove them in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops

I have a list with integers, in which every second int is zero (0), like this:

```
mylist = [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0]
```

I can only check single positions like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
     if i in mylist:
          #do something here
```

I am trying to check for two positions at every loop, so if the loop finds for example "2, 0" in mylist, it will be able to remove those two ints.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do with your checking... You can just get every other element with `mylist[::2]` ? What are you trying to remove? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Or maybe `for pair in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])`?

Comment: @JonClements trying to remove two integers, based on "i" in my loop. For example, i am searching for "3", and i want to remove both "3" and the "0" next to it..

Comment: @CDoc could the list also be `[9, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0]`? Eg... the values aren't related to indices?

Comment: @CDoc Could the list contain duplicates? like `[1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]` with search value of `3`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands nope! They are unique!

Comment: @JonClements yes, they are not ordered!

Answer (score 2):

Since the values between the `0`s are unique, you can simply use `list.index` to find the target value and then use `del` to delete this value and the next one from the `list`:

```
>>> my_list = [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0]
>>> my_index = my_list.index(3)
>>> del my_list[my_index:my_index+2]
>>> my_list
[1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example if you wanna remove the sequence `(2,0)`, taking into account flatten method mentionned below:

```
from itertools import izip, chain

>>> list(chain(*[[u,v] for u,v in izip(*[iter(mylist)]*2) if (u,v)!=(2,0)]))
[1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0]
```

All credits goes to:

[Creating a python dictionary from a line of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/creating-a-python-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text/4356415#4356415)

Comment: Just add some flattening to this and I think it's the most flexible here...

Comment: @JonClements Flexible, but perhaps a little overkill for the question, given their values apart from `0`s are unique? Also `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is the Pythonic way to flatten

Comment: @JonClements - Indeed, the question's subject line suggests checking for an arbitrary sequence of values (not even necessarily pairs). As long as these checks are meant not to be overlapping, this is a nice approach. I will say it's a little arcane, especially for Python beginners. I don't think there would be anything wrong with explicit looping instead.

Comment: Did not know the values are unique. Chris_Rabds answer is not ninja-ic and does well the job, despite no one liner.

Comment: Hm. I'm kind of disappointed by the edit. Using `sum()` as a "list concatenator" is arguably abuse of the function. As @Chris_Rands notes, this should be done with `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` (or `itertools.chain()` with the `*` operator).

Comment: @JohnY yeah... even a nested list-comp would be better than sum :)

Comment: I suspect for what looks like an assignment - Chris' answer is what's expected though...