# Python List - Searching for a value and its location

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for the greatest number out of a list to then obtain the element 1 location before If anyone knows how to do this it would be very much appreciated.

```
my_list = ['room', 10, 'chamber', 23, 'kitchen', 8]

pos = my_list.aMethodToGetTheGreatestValuePosition()

print('The biggest room is ' + my_list[pos-1])
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? (I don't think so)

Comment: I reopened it because the question is not exactly a duplicate as it is a unique case (has mixed strings and ints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. Note this requires structure, i.e. room, then size sequentially. I don't think that's a bad idea, since you should be using a dictionary or list of tuples anyway.

```
my_list = ['room', 10, 'chamber', 23, 'kitchen', 8]

pos = my_list.index(max(my_list[1::2]))  # 23

print('The biggest room is ' + my_list[pos-1])  # chamber
```

Comment: I like this one

Comment: Only thing I will note is that `str(...)` is useless

Comment: @jamylak Agreed & amended

Comment: That `index` call means you have to traverse the list twice.

Comment: @Turn There's nothing wrong with that. I realised this as well, but this is still the best solution because it's very unlikely to be the bottleneck and this solution is nice and simple. It is a completely valid solution

Comment: @Turn, agreed. I think the main issue from a holistic perspective is the choice of using a `list` in this way.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Agreed!

Comment: @jamylak Yeah, I didn't mean to say the solution was wrong, just pointing it out as I've found that some people seem think to `index` does some sort of magic reverse hash lookup. I apologize for the terseness.

Comment: No problem, i just thought it seemed like people were downvoting for this reason alone so decided to address it in general

Answer (score 1):

This will do it without having to traverse the list multiple times:

```
my_list = ['room', 10, 'chamber', 23, 'kitchen', 8]

pos = max(enumerate(my_list[1::2]), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

print('The biggest room is ' + my_list[2*pos])
```

This uses [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indexes of `my_list` at the same time it is searching for the max.

Or you can be slightly clever with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
print('The biggest room is ' +  max(zip(*[iter(my_list)]*2), key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

which relies upon using the same iterator over `my_list` to feed successive values to `zip` (borrowed from another [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/how-to-create-a-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text/4356415#4356415)). This essentially turns your flat list into a list of tuples which would be a nicer way of storing the original data, if you have that option:

```
>>> list(zip(*[iter(my_list)]*2))
[('room', 10), ('chamber', 23), ('kitchen', 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['room', 10, 'chamber', 23, 'kitchen', 8]

my_list[my_list.index(max(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), my_list)))-1]
```

Say there are 2 equal maximum numbers in the input list, it will take the first one. That will be a limitation to the solution

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
my_list = ['room', 10, 'chamber', 23, 'kitchen', 8]

max_index = max(range(len(mylist)),
                key=lambda i: my_list[i] if isinstance(my_list[i], int) else float('-inf'))
max_name = my_list[max_index-1]
```

I'd recommend changing your data format though, if you can. A dictionary mapping number to name would (or name to number) would be a lot more natural. Even a list of lists might be easier to deal with.

Comment: I'm interested in what you're proposing at the moment, can you give me a link to one of the data format structure so I can learn it myself ? Otherwise, thank you for your time

Comment: Dictionaries are pretty fundamental to Python. Read about them [in the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (I linked to the dictionary section in particular, but the whole page is probably good for you to read). You could use `{'room': 10, 'chamber': 23, 'kitchen': 8}` or something similar. Much easier to deal with than your interleaved list.