# Iterating over every two elements in a list

Tags: python, list

How do I make a `for` loop or a list comprehension so that every iteration gives me two elements?

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i,k in ???:
    print str(i), '+', str(k), '=', str(i+k)
```

Output:

```
1+2=3
3+4=7
5+6=11
```

Comment: For overlapping pair: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python

Comment: Next time avoid to name something just 'l'.
It can be quickly mixed up with some 1 or I or | 
Name it List 
... or L (if ya wanna save space *facepalm*).

Comment: Simply use a loop with two variables:
for i,k in zip(range(1,7)[0::2], range(1,7)[1::2]):
    print str(i), '+', str(k), '=', str(i+k)

Comment: As I've mentioned under the selected answer by @johnysweb below, the walrus operator can now be used (3.8+) to do this in a concise way: `for i, k in zip(_x := iter(mylist), _x): ...`

Answer (score 337, accepted):

You need a **`pairwise()`** (or **`grouped()`**) implementation.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

for x, y in pairwise(l):
   print("%d + %d = %d" % (x, y, x + y))
```

Or, more generally:

```
def grouped(iterable, n):
    "s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,s2n+2,...s3n-1), ..."
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

for x, y in grouped(l, 2):
   print("%d + %d = %d" % (x, y, x + y))
```

In Python 2, you should import [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) as a replacement for Python 3's built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

All credit to [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/creating-a-python-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text/4356415#4356415) to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4356329/78845), I have found this to be very efficient as it only iterates once over the list and does not create any unnecessary lists in the process.

**N.B**: This should not be confused with the [**`pairwise`** recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in Python's own [**`itertools`** documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), which yields `s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ...`, as pointed out by [@lazyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566644/lazyr) in the comments.

Little addition for those who would like to do type checking with **mypy** on Python 3:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def grouped(iterable: Iterable[T], n=2) -> Iterable[Tuple[T, ...]]:
    """s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), ..."""
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)
```

Comment: Not to be confused with the pairwise function suggested in the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) recipes section, which yields `s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...`

Comment: It does a different thing.  Your version only yields half the number of pairs compared to the `itertools` recipe function with the same name.  Of course yours is faster...

Comment: Huh? Your function and the function I referred to do different things, and that was the point of my comment.

Comment: @lazyr, @Sven: Oh, I *see*. Humble apologies. I should put my glasses on!

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I suspect the speed difference is due more to `itertools'` `pairwise()` being implemented in terms of `tee()` than because it returns less data for any given iterable -- of course it's also performing a somewhat different function altogether, so comparing them at all is questionable...

Comment: BE CAREFUL!  Using these functions puts you at risk of not iterating over the last elements of an iterable.  Example:
list(grouped([1,2,3],2))
>>> [(1, 2)]
.. when you'd expect [(1,2),(3,)]

Comment: @Erik49: In the case specified in the question, it wouldn't make sense to have an 'incomplete' tuple. If you wanted to include an incomplete tuple, you could use `izip_longest()` instead of `izip()`. E.g: `list(izip_longest(*[iter([1, 2, 3])]*2, fillvalue=0))` --> `[(1, 2), (3, 0)]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: But **to** be confused with the `grouper` recipe in the same documentation. It's definitely worth understanding how this works—that's how you can decide what to do with jagged groups (skip the leftover values, fill with a fillvalue, or return a short group).

Comment: @egafni do you how to fix your case?

Comment: @sailesh: You could use [`izip_longest()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list/5389547#comment20091344_5389547).

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks, but my use case is pretty small. So, I'm using `current, items = items[:25], items[25:]` in a while loop which checks for `len(items)`

Comment: Thanks, mate. Your solution worked fine to me and helped me to solve a problem I've spent quite a time on it.

Comment: With Python 3.8+ this can now be done in a more concise way by using the walrus operator: `unpack2 = lambda lst: zip(_x := iter(lst), _x); for a, b in unpack2(l)` (still need to define a function), or, without the lambda: `for a, b in zip(_l := iter(l), _l): ...` Add more `_l` to unpack 3 elements at a time or more.

Answer (score 279):

Well you need tuple of 2 elements, so

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i,k in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]):
    print str(i), '+', str(k), '=', str(i+k)
```

Where:

- `data[0::2]` means create subset collection of elements that `(index % 2 == 0)`
- `zip(x,y)` creates a tuple collection from x and y collections same index elements.

Comment: This can also be extended in case more  than two elements are required. For e.g. `for i, j, k in zip(data[0::3], data[1::3], data[2::3]):`

Comment: So much cleaner than pulling in an import and defining a function!

Comment: @kmarsh: But this only works on sequences, the function works on any iterable; and this uses O(N) extra space, the function doesn't; on the other hand, this is generally faster. There are good reasons to pick one or the other; being afraid of `import` is not one of them.

Comment: @abarnert `itertools.islice` to the rescue: `for i,k in zip(islice(data, 0, None, 2), islice(data, 1, None, 2):`. And, if you're worrying about "not iterating over the last elements of an iterable", replace `zip` with `itertools.zip_longest` and use a `fillvalue` that makes sense to you.

Comment: I needed to get `s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ...` and I got it using this > `for i,k in zip(data[0::1], data[1::1]):`

Comment: Will this create two new  lists?

Answer (score 101):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

>>> zip(l,l[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

>>> zip(l,l[1:])[::2]
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

>>> [a+b for a,b in zip(l,l[1:])[::2]]
[3, 7, 11]

>>> ["%d + %d = %d" % (a,b,a+b) for a,b in zip(l,l[1:])[::2]]
['1 + 2 = 3', '3 + 4 = 7', '5 + 6 = 11']
```

Comment: @HamidRohani `zip` returns a `zip` object in Python 3, which is not subscriptable. It needs to be converted to a sequence (`list`, `tuple`, etc.) first, but *"not working"* is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Just convert the `zip` object to a list of tuples like: `output = list(zip_object)`

Answer (score 78):

A simple solution.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    print str(l[i]), '+', str(l[i + 1]), '=', str(l[i] + l[i + 1])
```

Comment: what if your list is not even, and you want to just show the last number as it is?

Comment: @HansdeJong didn't get you. Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks. I figured already out how to do it. Problem was if you had a list that had not even amount of numbers in it, it would get an index error. Solved it with a try: except:

Comment: Or `((l[i], l[i+1])for i in range(0, len(l), 2))` for a generator, can be easily modified for longer tuples.

Answer (score 58):

While all the answers using `zip` are correct, I find that implementing the functionality yourself leads to more readable code:

```
def pairwise(it):
    it = iter(it)
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(it), next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            # no more elements in the iterator
            return
```

The `it = iter(it)` part ensures that `it` is actually an iterator, not just an iterable. If `it` already is an iterator, this line is a no-op.

Usage:

```
for a, b in pairwise([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    print(a + b)
```

Comment: This solution allows to generalization to size of tuples > 2

Comment: This solution also works if `it` is only an iterator and not an iterable. The other solutions seem to rely on the possibility to create two independent iterators for the sequence.

Comment: I found this approach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815056/2480481 before see this answer. Is cleaner, easier than dealing with zip().

Comment: I like that it allows to avoid tripling memory usage as the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't work nicely with `for` loops in Python 3.5+ due to [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/), which replaces any `StopIteration` raised in a generator with a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: @sidney thanks for the hint, but actually this only happens in Python 3.7+. Adjusting the reply accordingly.

Comment: Similar approach generalized and works in all python version.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63923008

Answer (score 43):

I hope this will be even more elegant way of doing it.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
zip(a[::2], a[1::2])

[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: take care with lists with an odd length! Will omit last element

Comment: Beautiful, I could not agree with you more. short sweet and elegant. I do have some questions since I am sort of new to some of python's libraries. Zip is one of them. first on a[::2] - if I understand correctly this will add 2 spaces for every iteration starting with the first value in the list. 1,3,5,etc. Now, on a[1::2] -

Comment: Now, on a[1::2] - this will add +1 from the first value 1+1 = 2. Then add +2 for all the other iterations. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: For the odd length use `from itertools import zip_longest`. It will return `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, None)]`

Answer (score 33):

In case you're interested in the performance, I did a small benchmark (using my library [`simple_benchmark`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark)) to compare the performance of the solutions and I included a function from one of my packages: [`iteration_utilities.grouper`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/grouper.html#iteration_utilities.grouper)

```
from iteration_utilities import grouper
import matplotlib as mpl
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder

bench = BenchmarkBuilder()

@bench.add_function()
def Johnsyweb(l):
    def pairwise(iterable):
        "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
        a = iter(iterable)
        return zip(a, a)

    for x, y in pairwise(l):
        pass

@bench.add_function()
def Margus(data):
    for i, k in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]):
        pass

@bench.add_function()
def pyanon(l):
    list(zip(l,l[1:]))[::2]

@bench.add_function()
def taskinoor(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        l[i], l[i+1]

@bench.add_function()
def mic_e(it):
    def pairwise(it):
        it = iter(it)
        while True:
            try:
                yield next(it), next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                return

    for a, b in pairwise(it):
        pass

@bench.add_function()
def MSeifert(it):
    for item1, item2 in grouper(it, 2):
        pass

bench.use_random_lists_as_arguments(sizes=[2**i for i in range(1, 20)])
benchmark_result = bench.run()
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 10)
benchmark_result.plot_both(relative_to=MSeifert)
```

[image]

So if you want the fastest solution without external dependencies you probably should just use the approach given by Johnysweb (at the time of writing it's the most upvoted and accepted answer).

If you don't mind the additional dependency then the `grouper` from `iteration_utilities` will probably be a bit faster.

### Additional thoughts

Some of the approaches have some restrictions, that haven't been discussed here.

For example a few solutions only work for sequences (that is lists, strings, etc.), for example Margus/pyanon/taskinoor solutions which uses indexing while other solutions work on any iterable (that is sequences **and** generators, iterators) like Johnysweb/mic_e/my solutions.

Then Johnysweb also provided a solution that works for other sizes than 2 while the other answers don't (okay, the `iteration_utilities.grouper` also allows setting the number of elements to "group").

Then there is also the question about what should happen if there is an odd number of elements in the list. Should the remaining item be dismissed? Should the list be padded to make it even sized? Should the remaining item be returned as single? The other answer don't address this point directly, however if I haven't overlooked anything they all follow the approach that the remaining item should be dismissed (except for taskinoors answer - that will actually raise an Exception).

With `grouper` you can decide what you want to do:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import grouper

>>> list(grouper([1, 2, 3], 2))  # as single
[(1, 2), (3,)]

>>> list(grouper([1, 2, 3], 2, truncate=True))  # ignored
[(1, 2)]

>>> list(grouper([1, 2, 3], 2, fillvalue=None))  # padded
[(1, 2), (3, None)]
```

Answer (score 20):

Use the `zip` and `iter` commands together:

I find this solution using `iter` to be quite elegant:

```
it = iter(l)
list(zip(it, it))
# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Which I found in the [Python 3 zip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
it = iter(l)
print(*(f'{u} + {v} = {u+v}' for u, v in zip(it, it)), sep='\n')

# 1 + 2 = 3
# 3 + 4 = 7
# 5 + 6 = 11
```

---

To generalise to `N` elements at a time:

```
N = 2
list(zip(*([iter(l)] * N)))
# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
for (i, k) in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]):
    print i, "+", k, "=", i+k
```

`zip(*iterable)` returns a tuple with the next element of each iterable.

`l[::2]` returns the 1st, the 3rd, the 5th, etc. element of the list: the first colon indicates that the slice starts at the beginning because there's no number behind it, the second colon is only needed if you want a 'step in the slice' (in this case 2).

`l[1::2]` does the same thing but starts in the second element of the lists so it returns the 2nd, the 4th, 6th, etc. element of the **original** list.

Comment: This answer was already given by Margus two years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list#answer-5389578

Comment: 1 for explaining how `[number::number]` syntax works. helpful for who doesn't use python often

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to do that. For example:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[(lst[i], lst[i+1]) for i,_ in enumerate(lst[:-1])]    
>>>[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*2))
>>>[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: This solution is so underrated. No external methods and manage odds case. Big up for you, sir.

Answer (score 9):

With unpacking:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
while l:
    i, k, *l = l
    print(f'{i}+{k}={i+k}')
```

Note: this will consume `l`, leaving it empty afterward.

Comment: Wow! Why I couldn't think about this :) You need to just handle case where there is no absolute pair (odd entries)

Comment: Nice and clever :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use [more_itertools](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#grouping) package.

```
import more_itertools

lst = range(1, 7)
for i, j in more_itertools.chunked(lst, 2):
    print(f'{i} + {j} = {i+j}')
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone it might help, here is a solution to a similar problem but with overlapping pairs (instead of mutually exclusive pairs).

From the Python [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Or, more generally:

```
from itertools import izip

def groupwise(iterable, n=2):
    "s -> (s0,s1,...,sn-1), (s1,s2,...,sn), (s2,s3,...,sn+1), ..."
    t = tee(iterable, n)
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(0, i):
            next(t[i], None)
    return izip(*t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The title of this question is misleading, you seem to be looking for consecutive pairs, but if you want to iterate over the set of all possible pairs than this will work :

```
for i,v in enumerate(items[:-1]):
        for u in items[i+1:]:
```

Answer (score 2):

A simplistic approach:

```
[(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
```

this is useful if your array is a and you want to iterate on it by pairs. 
To iterate on triplets or more just change the "range" step command, for example:

```
[(a[i],a[i+1],a[i+2]) for i in range(0,len(a),3)]
```

(you have to deal with excess values if your array length and the step do not fit)

Answer (score 2):

Another try at cleaner solution

```
def grouped(itr, n=2):
    itr = iter(itr)
    end = object()
    while True:
        vals = tuple(next(itr, end) for _ in range(n))
        if vals[-1] is end:
            return
        yield vals
```

---

For more customization options

```
from collections.abc import Sized

def grouped(itr, n=2, /, truncate=True, fillvalue=None, strict=False, nofill=False):
    if strict:
        if isinstance(itr, Sized):
            if len(itr) % n != 0:
                raise ValueError(f"{len(itr)=} is not divisible by {n=}")
    itr = iter(itr)
    end = object()
    while True:
        vals = tuple(next(itr, end) for _ in range(n))
        if vals[-1] is end:
            if vals[0] is end:
                return
            if strict:
                raise ValueError("found extra stuff in iterable")
            if nofill:
                yield tuple(v for v in vals if v is not end)
                return
            if truncate:
                return
            yield tuple(v if v is not end else fillvalue for v in vals)
            return
        yield vals
```

Comment: Like in my solution, you need to catch `StopIteration` now.

Comment: @mic_e I am using `next` with default value, it will not raise `StopIteration`

Answer (score 2):

The polished Python3 solution is given in one of the `itertools` [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought that this is a good place to share my generalization of this for n>2, which is just a sliding window over an iterable:

```
def sliding_window(iterable, n):
    its = [ itertools.islice(iter, i, None) 
            for i, iter
            in enumerate(itertools.tee(iterable, n)) ]                               

    return itertools.izip(*its)
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to divide a list by a number and fixed like this.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def divideByN(data, n):
        return [data[i*n : (i+1)*n] for i in range(len(data)//n)]  

>>> print(divideByN(l,2))
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

>>> print(divideByN(l,3))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using typing so you can verify data using [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) static analysis tool:

```
from typing import Iterator, Any, Iterable, TypeVar, Tuple

T_ = TypeVar('T_')
Pairs_Iter = Iterator[Tuple[T_, T_]]

def legs(iterable: Iterator[T_]) -> Pairs_Iter:
    begin = next(iterable)
    for end in iterable:
        yield begin, end
        begin = end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here we can have `alt_elem` method which can fit in your for loop.

```
def alt_elem(list, index=2):
    for i, elem in enumerate(list, start=1):
        if not i % index:
           yield tuple(list[i-index:i])


a = range(10)
for index in [2, 3, 4]:
    print("With index: {0}".format(index))
    for i in alt_elem(a, index):
       print(i)
```

Output:

```
With index: 2
(0, 1)
(2, 3)
(4, 5)
(6, 7)
(8, 9)
With index: 3
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
With index: 4
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Note: Above solution might not be efficient considering operations performed in func.

Answer (score -2):

This is simple solution, which is using range function to pick alternative elements from a list of elements.

Note: This is only valid for an even numbered list.

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
empty_list = [] 
for i in range(0, len(a_list), 2):
    empty_list.append(a_list[i] + a_list[i + 1])   
print(empty_list)
# [3, 7, 11]
```

Comment: Try providing an explanation rather than just code.

Comment: @LuisArgüelles's suggestion is especially critical here, where this question is a decade old and already has twenty answers. Imagine trying to sort through those answers to figure out which one is relevant? Try explaining what sets your answer apart and when your approach might be preferred. Are you relying on new syntax not addressed in the other answers? Is your approach faster or more efficient? Is it better suited for particular types of data (e.g., smaller arrays)?