# Iterating between 2 lists

Tags: python

I have 2 lists: 1 of which is a lists of lists. They are as follows-

```
lists_of_lists = ['1', '4', '7', '13', '16', '21', '32', '36'],['3', '6', '8', '14', '22', '26', '31', '40']

just_a_list =['THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG', 'IWOULDLOVETOGETOVERWITHTHISASSOONASPOSSIBLE']
```

The lists_of_lists are used for slicing the elements of just_a_list such that:
`['1', '4', '7', '13', '16', '21', '32', '36']` would slice the string `'THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG'` as follows

```
'1' - '4' - 'HEQU'
'7' - '13' - 'KBROWNF'
'16' - '21' - 'JUMPED'
'32' - '36' - 'ZYDOG'
```

points to note-

> Each list in `list_of_lists` will have an even number of numbers.
>
> The list at `i'th` position in `list_of_lists` will belong to the
>   string present at the `i'th` position in `just_a_list`.

Please help me out as to how do I carry out the process described above..

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework or a real-world problem? If the latter, you need to rethink the design of your data structures.

Comment: my "seems like a homework" senses are starting to tingle!

Comment: @levlevitsky - its homework. I can change the data structures if needed. Suggestions?

Comment: yes I agree, a dict might be a better choice `{'':[],'':[]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `zip()` to combine the string and slice lists, then use a `zip()` plus `iter()` trick to pair the start and stop values:

```
for slicelist, text in zip(lists_of_lists, just_a_list):
    for start, stop in zip(*([iter(slicelist)]*2)):
        print(text[int(start):int(stop) + 1])
```

Note that we have to *add* 1 to the stop index, as your appear to need it to be inclusive, while in Python the stop index is exclusive.

This gives:

```
>>> for slicelist, text in zip(lists_of_lists, just_a_list):
...     for start, stop in zip(*([iter(slicelist)]*2)):
...         print(text[int(start):int(stop) + 1])
... 
HEQU
KBROWNF
JUMPED
YDOG
ULDL
VETOGET
HTHIS
ONASPOSSIB
```

Comment: @julio.alegria: Note that I didn't explain how it all works in detail. If I was the teacher, I'd ask specific questions as to how the `zip(*([iter(slicelist)]*2))` part works..

Comment: This is so EPIC. Could you please explain it to me as to how the code works. i have no idea as to whats going on in there.

Comment: @begin.py: Ah, but there's the rub, innit. :-) I explained how *most* of it works. You can find the functions I used in the [Python functions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: @begin.py: The `zip()` + `iter()` stanza has been discussed here on Stack Overflow before, specifically in [Iterating over every two elements in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5389507)

Comment: @julio.alegria - I would love to show you the file i am working on. The code given here, will help me for just about 10% of my work.Once upon a time even you were a learner, even you needed help. Please dont comment if you cannot be constructive or helpfull.

Comment: @begin.py Of course I was (and still am) a learner, that's why I don't like these "do-my-homework" kind of questions, they don't help you to (guess what?) *learn*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right:

```
>>> ls = just_a_list =['THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG', 'IWOULDLOVETOGETOVERWITHTHISASSOONASPOSSIBLE']

>>> ls[0]
'THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG'

# so we do    
# your index was off by one
>>> ls[0][1:5]
'HEQU'

>>> ls[0][7:14]
'KBROWNF'
```