# Python list: exchange every n-th value with the (n+1)th

Tags: python, list

What is the best way to do this:

```
>>> replace2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Do you need to handle cases where there are an odd number of elements?

Comment: This question should be *replace every n value with n+1*

Comment: There's a really good discussion of going over multiple list elements here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def replace2inplace(lst):
    lst[1::2], lst[::2] = lst[::2], lst[1::2]
```

This uses slice assignment and slice step sizes to swap every pair in the list around, **in-place**:

```
>>> somelst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> replace2inplace(somelst)
>>> somelst
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Otherwise you could use some `itertools` tricks:

```
from itertools import izip, chain

def replace2copy(lst):
    lst1, lst2 = tee(iter(lst), 2)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(izip(lst[1::2], lst[::2])))
```

which gives:

```
>>> replace2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

with the `list()` call optional; if you only need to loop over the result the generator is enough:

```
from itertools import izip, chain, islice, tee

def replace2gen(lst):
    lst1, lst2 = tee(iter(lst))
    return chain.from_iterable(izip(islice(lst1, 1, None, 2), islice(lst2, None, None, 2)))

for i in replace2gen([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    print i
```

where `replace2gen()` can take arbitrary iterators too.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-place version:

```
def replace2(lst):
    return [x for pair in zip(lst[1::2], lst[::2]) for x in pair]
```

Answer (score 0):

My choice:

```
x = range(1,7)
res = [e for e in itertools.chain(*zip(x[1::2],x[0::2]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> sum([[x+1,x] for x in a if x&1 == True],[])
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

**EDIT:** Some further explanation was requested:

The code steps through each element in the list `a` and, if the element is odd (`x&1 == True`) it puts that element and the next element into a list in reverse order (`[x+1,x]`).

With out the `sum(...,[])` function we would have

```
[[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

The `sum(...,[])` function removes the internal square brackets giving

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

This can be done more generally by using the index of the list rather than its value:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> sum([[a[x],a[x-1]] for x in range(len(a)) if x&1 == True],[])
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

However, this will remove the last element of the list if its length is not even.