# Why doesn't QtConsole echo next()?

Tags: python, interpreter, jupyter, python-internals

I found this question about iterator behavior in Python:

[Python list iterator behavior and next(iterator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814984/python-list-iterator-behavior-and-nextiterator)

When I typed in the code:

```
a = iter(list(range(10)))
for i in a:
    print a
    next(a)
```

into the `jupyter-qtconsole` it returned:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

exactly as Martijn Pieters said it should when the interpreter doesn't echo the call to `next(a)`.

However, when I ran the same the code again in my Bash interpreter and IDLE, the code printed:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

to the console.

I ran the code:

```
import platform
platform.python_implementation()
```

in all three environments and they all said I ran `'CPython'`.

**So why does the QtConsole suppress the `next(a)` call when IDLE and Bash don't?**

If it helps, I'm running Python 2.7.9 on Mac OSX and using the Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a choice the developers of `IPython` (on which the `QtConsole` is based) made regarding what should be echoed back to the user.

Specifically, in the [`InteractiveShell`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L198) class that is used, function [`run_ast_nodes`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2770) is, by default, defined with an `interactivity='last_expr'`. The documentation on this attribute states:

```
interactivity : str
  'all', 'last', 'last_expr' or 'none', specifying which nodes should be
  run interactively (displaying output from expressions). 'last_expr'
  will run the last node interactively only if it is an expression (i.e.
  expressions in loops or other blocks are not displayed. Other values
  for this parameter will raise a ValueError.
```

As you can see: ***expressions in loops or other blocks are not displayed***.

You can change this in the config files for `IPython` and get it to work like your `repl` if you really need to. Point is, it was just a preference the designers made.