# Is calling next(iter) inside for i in iter supported in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, pep

Question: [Python list iterator behavior and next(iterator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814984/python-list-iterator-behavior-and-nextiterator) documents the fact that calling

```
for i in iter:
    ...
    next(iter)
```

Has the effect of skipping ahead in the for loop.  Is this defined behavior that I can rely on (e.g. in some PEP) or merely an accident of implementation that could change without warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what `iter` is. If it’s an *iterator* created with a call of `iter()` on an iterable, then yes, calling `next(iter)` will also advance the iterator:

```
>>> it = iter(range(4))
>>> for x in it:
        print(x)
        _ = next(it)

0
2
```

It’s important that `it` is an *iterator* (instead of just any iterable) since the for loop will internally also call `iter()` on that object. Since iterators (usually) return themselves when `iter(some_iterator)` is called, this works fine.

Is this a good idea though? Generally not since it can easily break:

```
>>> it = iter(range(3))
>>> for x in it:
        print(x)
        _ = next(it)

0
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 3, in <module>
    _ = next(it)
StopIteration
```

You would have to add exception handling for the `StopIteration` exception manually inside the loop; and that gets messy very easily. Of course you could also use a default value, e.g. `next(it, None)` instead, but that becomes confusing quickly, especially when you’re not actually using the value for anything.

This whole concept also breaks as soon as someone later decides to not use an iterator but some other iterable in the for loop (for example because they are refactoring the code to use a list there, and then everything breaks).

You should attempt to let the for loop be the only one that consumes the iterator. Change your logic so that you can easily determine whether or not an iteration should be skipped: If you can, filter the iterable *first*, before starting the loop. Otherwise, use conditionals to skip iterations within the loop (using `continue`):

```
>>> it = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(3))
>>> for x in it:
        print(x)

0
2

>>> it = range(3) # no need for an iterator here
>>> for x in it:
        if x % 2 == 1:
            continue
        print(x)

0
2
```

Comment: In your example `range(0,3,2)` would suffice

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah, I didn’t want to rely on the `range()` functionality here though. My point is that these ways would work with any kind of iterable.

Answer (score 1):

In for loop, it always call `next` of the iterating item.

if you call `next()` before for loop calls next, then it has the effect of skipping the (next) item.

So, being said that, you can implement this in your program, as long as `for` calls the same method (next).

So far, even in `3.6` the same being implemented. so, there is no need to worry.