# How do I compute the derivative of an array in python

Tags: python

**How do I compute the derivative of an array**, y (say), with respect to another array, x (say) - both arrays from a certain experiment?

e.g.

`y = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]` and `x = [.1,.2,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9]`;

I want to get `dy/dx`!

Comment: Functions have derivatives, not sets of values. If we defined a function `dydx(x=[.1,.2,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9], y=[1,2,3,4,4,5,6])`, what would you expect the return value to look like?

Comment: Do you wish to calculate derivative function? or just values over given intervals?

Comment: use NumPy: https://github.com/tiagopereira/python_tips/wiki/Numpy%3A-numerical-derivatives

Comment: in your case it looks like `y = 10x` => derivative is `y=10` I think ... Im not sure I understood the question

Comment: Dy / dx means difference in Y, divided by difference in X, otherwise known as the slope between the two points (x_1, y_1) and (x_2, y_2). Just subtract two adjacent elements in `y[]`, and divide by the difference in the two corresponding elements in `x[]`.

Answer (score 49):

Use **[numpy.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)**

If dx is constant

```
from numpy import diff
dx = 0.1
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
dy = diff(y)/dx
print dy 
array([ 10.,  10.,  10.,   0.,  10.,  10.])
```

dx is not constant (your example)

```
from numpy import diff
x = [.1, .2, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
dydx = diff(y)/diff(x)
print dydx 
[10., 3.33333,  10. ,   0. , 10. ,  10.]
```

Note that this approximated "derivative" has size `n-1` where `n` is your array/list size.

Don't know what you are trying to achieve but here are some ideas:

- If you are trying to make [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) maybe [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) formulation might help you better.
- The solution above is like a first-order accuracy approximation for the [forward schema of finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) with a non-uniform grid/array.

Answer (score 23):

**use `numpy.gradient()`**

Please be aware that there are more advanced way to calculate the numerical derivative than simply using `diff`. I would suggest to use `numpy.gradient`, like in this example.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# we sample a sin(x) function
dx = np.pi/10
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,np.pi/10)

# we calculate the derivative, with np.gradient
plt.plot(x,np.gradient(np.sin(x), dx), '-*', label='approx')

# we compare it with the exact first derivative, i.e. cos(x)
plt.plot(x,np.cos(x), label='exact')
plt.legend()
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming this is what you meant:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> x = [.1,.2,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9]
>>> y = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable): # question 5389507
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
...     a = iter(iterable)
...     return izip(a, a)
... 
>>> for ((a, b), (c, d)) in zip(pairwise(x), pairwise(y)):
...   print (d - c) / (b - a)
... 
10.0
10.0
10.0
>>>
```

[question 5389507 link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507)

That is, define `dx` as the difference between adjacent elements in `x`.

Comment: I love functional programming as much as the next guy, but this answer is needlessly complicated.

Comment: This computes every other difference, which is clearly not what the question is asking for. If you want to debate 'clearly' given the succientness of the OP, note this answer doesn't handle the fact that x and y have an odd number of elements in his question.   Answers using np.diff are correct.

Answer (score 4):

[numpy.diff(x)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) computes

> the difference between adjacent elements in x

just like in the answer by @tsm.
As a result you get an array which is 1 element shorter than the original one. This of course makes sense, as you can only start computing the differences from the first index (1 "history element" is needed).

```
>>> x = [1,3,4,6,7,8]
>>> dx = numpy.diff(x)
>>> dx
array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1])

>>> y = [1,2,4,2,3,1]
>>> dy = numpy.diff(y)
>>> dy
array([ 1,  2, -2,  1, -2])
```

Now you can divide those 2 resulting arrays to get the desired derivative.

```
>>> d = dy / dx
>>> d
array([ 0.5,  2. , -1. ,  1. , -2. ])
```

If for some reason, you need a relative (to the y-values) growth, you can do it the following way:

```
>>> d / y[:-1]
array([ 0.5       ,  1.        , -0.25      ,  0.5       , -0.66666667])
```

Interpret as 50% growth, 100% growth, -25% growth, etc.

Full code:

```
import numpy
x = [1,3,4,6,7,8]
y = [1,2,4,2,3,1]
dx = numpy.diff(x)
dy = numpy.diff(y)
d = dy/dx
```

Comment: Please provide some sort of explanation, along with the code.

Comment: While this might be a valid answer, it would be better if you elaborate on that, so that feature visitors can learn from this.

Comment: @Pablo Please read [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). While code-only answers aren't great, they generally shouldn't be deleted either

Comment: @Machavity thanks for the link, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me, @Nick . I updated my answer, hope it makes sense.