# How to find slope of curve at certain points

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means, gradient-descent

how to find slope at certain points circled in blue in below curve ? Are these below 2 approaches valid ? though they give different results .
How to automatically find the points where the slope changes drastically in curve  like around at point 5,6 in below graph

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ]

y=[512, 256, 128, 64 , 32 , 16 , 8  , 7  , 6  , 5  , 4  , 3  , 2  , 1  ]
```

1. Numpy gradient give below result

np.gradient(y)

```
[-256. , -192. ,  -96. ,  -48. ,  -24. ,  -12. ,   -4.5,   -1. ,-1. ,   -1. ,   -1. ,   -1. ,   -1. ,   -1. ]
```

can we use numpy.gradient to find the slope of curve ? since finding slope of line and curve is bit different [Shown in this link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/slope-of-a-curve-basic/)

2.Using custom slope function

```
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    return m


slope_value=[]
for i in range(len(y)):
    i += 1
    v=slope(y[i], x[i], y[i-1], x[i-1])
    print(i,v)
    slope_value.append(v)



result: [-0.00390625,  -0.0078125,  -0.015625,  -0.03125,  -0.0625,  -0.125,  -1.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,  -1.0]
```

[image]

Comment: To find a slope that makes sense, you'd need to fit a function to your datapoints. Otherwise they are just finite differences (if that's what you are satisfied with - that's okay).

Comment: @ amzon-ex ,why slope make sese by fitting a function to datapoints  as i just want to find slope and not interested to optimized any parameters of any function  . np.gradient(y) dose not fit any function we are passing just an array .

Comment: @star have you tried some solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876290/how-do-i-compute-derivative-using-numpy? An issue with using `np.gradient` is that it is an approximation of derivative using a convolution. here's one that's directly applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841729/how-do-i-compute-the-derivative-of-an-array-in-python