# Handling indefinite paired arguments with argparse

Tags: python, dictionary, command-line-arguments, argparse

In [my project](https://github.com/vermiculus/mcraw#adding-recipes), I need to define a syntax like

```
mcraw recipe add COUNT ID COUNT_1 ID_1 [COUNT_2 ID_2 ..]
```

and [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) seems to be the best tool for the general job.

How can I instruct Python and its `argparse` to construct a dictionary like this?

```
{
  ID_1: COUNT_1,
  ID_2: COUNT_2,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you modify the syntax slightly to `mcraw recipe add COUNT ID COUNT_1,ID1 COUNT_2,ID2 ...`? This would make writing a custom action which processes each comma-delimted pair and adds the corresponding dictionary much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your arguments in pairs:

```
argdict = {args[i + 1]: args[i] for i in xrange(0, len(args), 2)}
```

`argparse` has otherwise no special handling for this kind of input.

Comment: Same answer, but different syntax: `argdict = {arg1: arg2 for (arg1, arg2) in zip(*[iter(args)]*2)}` as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/778533

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: sure, but in Python 2 `zip()` produces a list, not an iterator, which is why that answer uses `itertools.izip()` instead. There is more than one way to solve the pairwise iteration problem.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: but once you use `zip()` / `izip()`, just use `dict()` and not a dict comprehenion: `a = iter(args); argdict = dict(izip(a, a))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the wrong approach here. Why not point to a `.json` file for your program to accept on the commandline?

That way

```
$> python mcraw recipe add --recipies=my_recipies.json
```

And you can pull it in and use it however you like, possibilities include such as what is in [Martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126073/881224) answer

Comment: Can you expand on why JSON would be a better format?  I'm more than open to suggestions as to how this should work; I haven't actually designed the database yet.  Would you edit in a potential format for the JSON file?

Comment: I feel it's simpler to create the data for the application before hand, but if that's not possible, creating a dictionary and using `json.dumps` is easy too. Modifying individual entries is a piece of cake as well. Do you want me to continue?