# How to create argument of type "list of pairs" with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I need to let the end user of my python script types something like:

```
script.py -sizes <2,2> <3,3> <6,6>
```

where each element of the `-sizes` option is a pair of two positive integers. How can I achieve this with `argparse` ?

Comment: Is the input exactly `<2,2> <3,3>` or `2,2 3,3 4,4`

Comment: @idjaw There is no specification on the input. i just need to let the user enters sizes made of two integers (x and y dimensions)

Comment: `nargs=2` and `action='append'` lets you parse '--s 2 2 -s 3 3 -s 6 6'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling indefinite paired arguments with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126062/handling-indefinite-paired-arguments-with-argparse)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define a custom type:

```
def pair(arg):
    # For simplity, assume arg is a pair of integers
    # separated by a comma. If you want to do more
    # validation, raise argparse.ArgumentError if you
    # encounter a problem.
    return [int(x) for x in arg.split(',')]
```

then use this as the type for a regular argument:

```
p.add_argument('--sizes', type=pair, nargs='+')
```

Then

```
>>> p.parse_args('--sizes 1,3 4,6'.split())
Namespace(sizes=[[1, 3], [4, 6]])
```

Comment: But watch out for '--sizes 1, 3 4, 6'.  The shell will split these pairs.

Comment: I put that in the category of user error; the correct use of `--sizes` as defined *requires* that the arguments be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Argparse doesn't try to cover all possible formats of input data. You can always get `sizes` as string and parse them with few lines of code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--sizes', nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    sizes = [tuple(map(int, s.split(',', maxsplit=1))) for s in args.sizes]
except Exception:
    print('sizes cannot be parsed')

print(sizes)
```

"Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."