# Python write text to CSV with two columns

Tags: python, csv

Hi I have a small problem here.

I have a text file with numbers which looks like this

```
2.131583
2.058964
6.866568
0.996470
6.424396
0.996004
6.421990
```

And with

```
fList = [s.strip() for s in open('out.txt').readlines()]
outStr = ''
for i in fList:
      outStr += (i+',')
f = open('text_to_csv.csv', 'w')
f.write(outStr.strip())
f.close()
```

I am able to generate a CSV and all the data is stored in it, but all in one row.
I would like to have them in two columns.

Is there any easy addition that would make the CSV look like this?

```
2.131583 2.058964
6.866568 0.996470
6.424396 0.996004
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over every two elements in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: You might also want to look into the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Do you really want to loose the last number of your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fList = [s.strip() for s in open('out.txt').readlines()]
outStr = ''
count = 0
for i in fList:
      outStr += (i+',')
      if count % 2 == 0: # You can replace 2 with what ever number you of columns you need
          outStr += ('\r\n') # Make the return correct for your system
      count += 1
f = open('text_to_csv.csv', 'w')
f.write(outStr.strip())
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot, count = 0 was causing that the first row only had one value, count = 1 made it correct.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be using csv module. You can write like

```
import csv

with open('text_to_csv.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for i in range(0, len(fList), 2):
        writer.writerow(fList[i:i+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list (from reading the file) in memory, just reformat the list into what you want:

```
input='''\
2.131583
2.058964
6.866568
0.996470
6.424396
0.996004
6.421990'''    

cols=2

data=input.split()       # proxy for a file
print data
print '==='
for li in [data[i:i+cols] for i in range(0,len(data),cols)]:
    print li
```

Prints:

```
['2.131583', '2.058964', '6.866568', '0.996470', '6.424396', '0.996004', '6.421990']
===
['2.131583', '2.058964']
['6.866568', '0.996470']
['6.424396', '0.996004']
['6.421990']
```

Or, use a N-at-a-time file reading idiom:

```
import itertools
cols=2
with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin:
    for li in itertools.izip_longest(*[fin]*cols):
        print li  
# prints
('2.131583\n', '2.058964\n')
('6.866568\n', '0.996470\n')
('6.424396\n', '0.996004\n')
('6.421990', None)
```

Which you can combine into one iterator in, one iterator out if you want a type of file filter:

```
import itertools
cols=2
with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin, open('/tmp/nout.txt','w') as fout:
    for li in itertools.izip_longest(*[fin]*cols):
        fout.write('\t'.join(e.strip() for e in li if e)+'\n')
```

The output file will now be:

```
2.131583    2.058964
6.866568    0.996470
6.424396    0.996004
6.421990
```

If you only want to write the output of there are the full set of numbers, i.e., the remainder numbers at the end of the file that are less than `cols` in total length:

```
import itertools
cols=2
# last number '6.421990' not included since izip is used instead of izip_longest
with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin, open('/tmp/nout.txt','w') as fout:
    for li in itertools.izip(*[fin]*cols):
        fout.write('\t'.join(e.strip() for e in li)+'\n')
```

Then the output file is:

```
2.131583    2.058964
6.866568    0.996470
6.424396    0.996004
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
with open('out.txt', 'r') as fList, open('text_to_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in fList:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n' if i% 2 == 0 else '\t')`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in storing the entries from the original file in a new list but just want the output file, you can also do something like this:

```
fList = [s.strip() for s in open('out.txt').readlines()]
f = open('text_to_csv.csv', 'w')
for i in range(0,len(fList)-1,2):
    f.write(fList[i] + "," + fList[i+1] + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not really sure what you mean, but i think your expected output is:

```
2.131583,2.058964,
6.866568,0.996470,
6.424396,0.996004,
6.421990
```

My code for this:

```
with open('out.txt', 'r') as fif, open('text_to_csv.csv', 'w') as fof:
    fList = ','.join([v.strip() if i % 2 else '\n'+v.strip()
                      for i, v in enumerate(fif.readlines())])[1:]
    fof.write(fList)
```

Interesting points:

If you want to get rid of the trailing "," at the end of your file, just concatenate the list via the `join()` function.

`flat_string = ','.join([item1,...,])`

For leading linebreak on odd-items in the list i have enumerated it.

`index, value enumerate([item1,...,])`

And find the odd-items via the modulo-operator `index % 2`.

With an "inline-if" you can check this on the fly.

At least i exclude the redundant linebreak at the beginning on the string with `[1:]`