# Accepting an unknown number of variables using input()

Tags: python

I am trying to create a bounded rectangle using a random number of points that are provided by the user. The reason this is difficult for me is because all the numbers must be accepted on only one line, I don't know how many variables the user will provide, and since I am accepting points, I must have the right amount (evens).

Here is a sample run:

```
Enter the points: 
``>>>4 1 3 5 1 5 9 0 2 5
```

My primary question is how do I unpack a random number of points? And also, how do I pair the even points together?

Comment: as for your second question: `even, odd = points[1::2], points[0::2]`, assuming that you count element `[0]` as first (odd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
points = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

In Python 3:

```
points = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Another method - list comprehension:

```
points = [int(p) for p in input().split()]
```

To pair x and y of the points together you can use something like `pairwise()` on the `points` list: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/220700 for details.

Answer (score 1):

If they are read as a string, you can use the [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method, which will return a `list`, then use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) to convert the items of the list to integers:

```
points_input = raw_input("Enter the points:")

points = map(int, points_input.split())
print points
```

**Notes**

- The result (`points`) will be a `list` of integers.
- If you are using Python 3.x, you have to use the method `input()` instead of `raw_input()`.