# How to subtract every n-1 item from every nth item in an array (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays

I've looked into the many posts about getting every nth item of an array, and I used the method for slicing even and odd indices. However, I end up with an empty array for the final object. Any suggestions?

`floc1` is an array, and I want to subtract every odd element from every even element:

```
period = abs(floc1[0::2] - floc1[1::2])
```

This currently gives me an empty array.

EDIT:

I've tried everything suggested in the comments below. The only thing that generated a different error was:

```
period = [i-j for i, j in zip(floc1[0::2], floc1[1::2])]
```

This gives:

```
Phi12 = ((tau)/(period))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,8208) (0,)
```

In reference to:

```
Phi12 = ((tau)/(period))
```

Again, `floc1` is definitely not an empty array. I saved it to a text file to confirm.

Comment: is `floc1` a numpy array?

Comment: Yes, `floc1` is a numpy array. It's generated from a loop previously:

`if len(locs2) > len(locs):
    floc2 = np.transpose(locs2[0:len(locs):1])
    floc1 = np.transpose(locs)
else:
    floc1 = np.transpose(locs[0:len(locs2):1])
    floc2 = np.transpose(locs2)
np.savetxt('floc1.txt', floc1)
np.savetxt('floc2.txt', floc2)`

Comment: maybe something is going wrong in that process. Can you try printing floc1 (or len(floc1) if it is large) to narrow down the problem?

Comment: `floc1` is huge. When I run the print command, I get:

`[[   132    133    134 ..., 147102 147103 147104]]`. 

`len(floc1)` returns `1`.

Also, I saved `floc1` as a text file, and I can see all the values. It's not empty.

Comment: There's your problem. `floc1[0]` is the array you should be operating on.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I never would have caught that.

Comment: @gnibbler, I'm having some more difficulties. I didn't notice until now, but the `period` array contains only values of `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example gives an error if `floc1` is a `list` (which people often call an "array"). For a `list` you can do it this way.

```
>>> floc1 = [11, 5, 6, 2]
>>> it = iter(floc1)
>>> [x - next(it) for x in it]
[6, 4]
```

You can also use `zip` if you prefer see @wenzul's answer

If `floc1` is a numpy.array - what you have already works

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> floc1 = np.array([11, 5, 6, 2])
>>> abs(floc1[0::2] - floc1[1::2])
array([6, 4])
```

Perhaps your `floc1` is actually an empty array

Comment: That gives me this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration`

Comment: @RobbieCapps, that means you have an odd number of items in the array. Can you specify what should happen in that case?

Comment: For this case, it's only important that as many of the values as possible are used. So if I just end up with one less than I started with, that's fine.

Comment: I read your edit. I thought the same thing, but I saved `floc1` as a text file using `np.savetext`. It contains the values I would expect.

Comment: @RobbieCapps, in that case `zip` is better as it will silently truncate the extra value.

Comment: @RobbieCapps, np.array would give `ValueError` if the slices are different sizes

Comment: I would expect the slices to be of different sizes, but I don't see `ValueError`. I tried with `zip`, and I still end up with an empty array. No errors.

Comment: `[i-j for i, j in zip(v[0::2], v[1::2])]` seems to work pretty well (both with native arrays and numpy arrays).

Comment: @xbug, yes zip will work fine, but be much slower than using native numpy operations.

Comment: @gnibbler, I tried this:

    `for i, k in zip(floc1[0::2], floc1[1::2]):
        if len(i) > len(k):
            i_2 = (i[0:len(k):1])
            k_2 = (k[0:len(k):1])
        else:
                i_2 = (i[0:len(i):1])
                k_2 = (k[0:len(i):1])
            
        period = abs(i_2-k_2)
        np.savetxt('Period.txt', period)`

I'm still returned with an empty array.

Comment: @xbug, I tried that too, but I am also returned with an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you try to substract a list from a list.
You need to do that element-wise.

```
>>> for i, k in zip(floc1[0::2], floc1[1::2]):
...     print abs(i-k)
```

Also look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list).