# separate a string 2 by 2 using Python3 macadress format

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

i want to use a function like "{}".format (variable)
so i can transform a string like: "

> A1B345FS

"
And i want to have something like: "

> A1:B3:45:FS

"
i am not able to use a while or a for.

Can i use .join (variable)  ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over every two elements in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character?

Comment: No, i need to insert the " : " every 2 characters and without the use of a while or a for cicle.

I allready have a for cicle to do this, but i wounder if there is some clean way.

i = 0
resul = ""
for r in mac:
    i += 1
    resul += r
    if i == 2:
        resul += ":"
        i = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code solves the problem.

```
import re
s = "A1B345FS"
s2=re.findall('..',s)
s3=":".join(s2)

print(s3)
```