# How to convert list pairs into tuple pairs

Tags: python

How do you turn a list that contain pairs into a list that contains tuple pairs by using easy programming e.g for loop? x,y = ...?

My code:

```
def read_numbers():
    numbers = ['68,125', '113,69', '65,86', '108,149', '152,53', '78,90']
    numbers.split(',')
    x,y = tuple numbers
    return numbers
```

desire output:

```
[(68,125), (113,69), (65,86), (108,149), (152,53), (78,90)]
```

Comment: please search accross the web: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303060-group-a-list-into-sequential-n-tuples/

Comment: i wouldn't post here if i found it on the web :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine a list into tuple pairs (x, y) - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769734/combine-a-list-into-tuple-pairs-x-y-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def read_numbers():
    numbers = ['68,125', '113,69', '65,86', '108,149', '152,53', '78,90']
    return [tuple(map(int,pair.split(','))) for pair in numbers]
```

Comment: thank you! it worked! How can you do this without the map() method?

Answer (score 2):

Try this by using nested list comprehension:

```
o = [tuple(int(y) for y in x.split(',')) for x in numbers]
```

Comment: You  can omit the `[]` brackets in the `tuple` constructor. No need build a  `list`,  just pass the generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just use list comprehension. Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)!

```
# Pass in numbers as an argument so that it will work
# for more than 1 list.
def read_numbers(numbers):
    return [tuple(int(y) for y in x.split(",")) for x in numbers]
```

Here is a breakdown and explanation (in comments) of the list comprehension:

```
[
    tuple(                              # Convert whatever is between these parentheses into a tuple
            int(y)                      # Make y an integer
            for y in                    # Where y is each element in
            x.split(",")                # x.split(","). Where x is a string and x.split(",") is a list
                                        # where the string is split into a list delimited by a comma.
    ) for x in numbers                  # x is each element in numbers
]
```

However, if you are just doing it for one list, there is no need to create a function.

Comment: You  can omit the `[]` brackets in the `tuple` constructor. No need build a  `list`,  just pass the generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def read_numbers():
    numbers = ['68,125', '113,69', '65,86', '108,149', '152,53', '78,90']
    final_list = []
    [final_list.append(tuple(int(test_str) for test_str in number.split(','))) for number in numbers]
    return final_list
```