# How to concatenate strings into parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, concatenation

In Python I have this loop that e.g. prints some value:

```
for row in rows:
    toWrite = row[0]+","
    toWrite += row[1]
    toWrite += "\n"
```

Now this works just fine, and if I print "toWrite" it would print this:

```
print toWrite

#result:,
A,B
C,D
E,F
... etc
```

My question is, how would I concatenate these strings with parenthesis and separated with commas, so result of loop would be like this:

```
(A,B),(C,D),(E,F) <-- the last item in parenthesis, should not contain - end with comma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd [group your items into pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list), then use string formatting and `str.join()`:

```
','.join(['({},{})'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(*[iter(rows)] * 2)])
```

- The `zip(*[iter(rows)] * 2)` expression produces elements from `rows` in pairs.
- Each pair is formatted with `'({},{})'.format(*pair)`; the two values in `pair` are slotted into each `{}` placeholder.
- The `(A,B)` strings are joined together into one long string using `','.join()`. Passing in a list comprehension is marginally faster than using a generator expression here as `str.join()` would otherwise convert it to a list *anyway* to be able to scan it twice (once for the output size calculation, once for building the output).

Demo:

```
>>> rows = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
>>> ','.join(['({},{})'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(*[iter(rows)] * 2)])
'(A,B),(C,D),(E,F),(G,H)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import islice, izip
','.join(('(%s, %s)' % (x, y) for x, y in izip(islice(rows, 0, None, 2), islice(rows, 1, None, 2))))
```

Generator and iterators are adopted here.
See [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for a reference.