# Using map to generate a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say, I have a list of x,y coordinates like:

```
all_coordinates = [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4...]
```

And there is a method:

```
def rotate_xy_by_theta(self, x, y, theta):
    # does the maths
    returns new_x, new_y
```

which returns the `new_x,new_y` position for each pair of coordinates given a particular `x, y` input values for a given `theta`.

I now want to iterate through all items in the above list in pair and generate a new list `modified_coordinates`.

I can do this easily with a traditional for-loop.

Can this be done with the `map` function ?

Something like:

```
theta = 90    
modified_coordinates = map(self.rotate_xy_by_theta(x, y, theta), all_coordinates)
```

My issue is how to get `x,y` values in pair in the above `map` function.

Comment: Why don't you use a better structure to store your coordinates? Even something like `all_coordinates = [[x1,x2,x3,x4],[y1,y2,y3,y4]]`

Comment: Oh I wish I could do it. I get `all_coordinates` from an api which is not under my control.

Comment: well you can get the x coords by `x_coords = all_coordinates[::1]` and the y coords by `y = all_coordinates[1::2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with `map()` directly, because you are not applying a function to each individual value in your input. You need to pair up the values in the input, and add an extra argument to your function each time. Your function also returns a *tuple* of coordinates, depending on your needs you may have to flatten out the results again.

Using the tools from [Iterating over every two elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list) and a list comprehension is the better option here:

```
theta = 90
per_two = zip(*([iter(all_coordinates)] * 2))
modified_coordinates = [self.rotate_xy_by_theta(x, y, theta) for x, y in per_two]
```

This gives you a list of `(new_x, new_y)` tuples, arguably a better format to continue processing. If you do need this flattened out again, you can add another loop:

```
modified_coordinates = [coord for x, y in per_two for coord in self.rotate_xy_by_theta(x, y, theta)]
```

If you need `modified_coordinates` to be a lazy generator (like `map()` is in Python 3) you can make it a generator expression instead:

```
modified_coordinates = (self.rotate_xy_by_theta(x, y, theta) for x, y in per_two)
```

or flattened:

```
modified_coordinates = (coord for x, y in per_two for coord in self.rotate_xy_by_theta(x, y, theta))
```