# Python invert every two elements of list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, reverse

I have a list in Python and I am looking to invert every pair of elements in the list. Here is the list:

```
list_ty = ['many_ord','many','12_FH_Temp_ord','12_FH_Temp','Celsius_ord','Celsius','Pressure_Pas_ord','Pressure_Pas','Kelvin_ord','Kelvin']
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
list_out = ['many','many_ord','12_FH_Temp','12_FH_Temp_ord','Celsius','Celsius_ord','Pressure_Pas','Pressure_Pas_ord','Kelvin','Kelvin_ord']
```

**Additional Information:**

There will always be an even number of elements in the list.

The item ending with `_ord` will always come before the item without `_ord`.

**Question:**

Is there a way to reverse the order of each item ending with `_ord` and the following (associated) item without `_ord`?

Comment: The key iterating over a list by pairs of elements, for which there a lot of answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this way:

```
>>> sum(zip(list_ty[1::2], list_ty[::2]), ())
('many', 'many_ord', '12_FH_Temp', '12_FH_Temp_ord', 'Celsius', 'Celsius_ord',     'Pressure_Pas', 'Pressure_Pas_ord', 'Kelvin', 'Kelvin_ord')
>>>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! I like this and it works as I require.

Comment: Just a warning if performance is ever a concern: This will construct and destroy an enormous number of `tuple`s; the two element ones made by `zip` can be made close to free by using the Py3 version of `zip` from `future_builtins`, but it will create a series of len 2, len 4, len 6, etc. `tuple`s, rebuilding once for every pair of elements in `list_ty`. If the `list` is known to be smallish, then no big deal, but if it could be longish, then basically all of the other solutions are superior since they avoid creation of tons of temporaries during operation.

Answer (score 9):

Use a `for` loop and step 2 elements at a time. You can use the basic python variable swap then:

```
a, b = b, a
```

---

```
list_ty = ['many_ord','many','12_FH_Temp_ord','12_FH_Temp','Celsius_ord','Celsius','Pressure_Pas_ord','Pressure_Pas','Kelvin_ord','Kelvin']

for i in range(0, len(list_ty), 2):
    list_ty[i], list_ty[i+1] = list_ty[i+1], list_ty[i]
```

`list_ty` has the following value after this loop:

```
['many', 'many_ord', '12_FH_Temp', '12_FH_Temp_ord', 'Celsius', 'Celsius_ord', 'Pressure_Pas', 'Pressure_Pas_ord', 'Kelvin', 'Kelvin_ord']
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit silly as a one-liner, but here you go:

```
from itertools import chain

list_out = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_ty[1::2], list_ty[::2])))
```

To explain: We're using slicing by step 2 with offset 1 to get the values in the odd indices, and another slice by step 2 with offset 0 to get the even indices. We `zip` them together, making `[even, odd, even, odd,...]` into `((odd, even), (odd, even), ...)`, then using `chain.from_iterable` to flatten out those `tuple`s, and `list` to realize the `chain` generator for us.

Answer (score 2):

The lazy way:

```
>>> [x + y for x in list_ty if not x.endswith('_ord') for y in ('', '_ord')]
['many', 'many_ord', '12_FH_Temp', '12_FH_Temp_ord', 'Celsius', 'Celsius_ord', 'Pressure_Pas', 'Pressure_Pas_ord', 'Kelvin', 'Kelvin_ord']
```

Ignore any entries that end in "_ord", and just alternatingly add it to the other elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, and here's one with `range(len())`:

```
list_out = [list_ty[idx+2*(not idx%2)-1] for idx in range(len(list_ty))]
```

This goes through each possible index in the original list and grabs the item either before or after that index.

0 would grab the item at index `0 + 2*(not 0%2)-1` or `0 + 2*(not 0)-1` or `0 + 2*1-1` or `1`.

1 would grab the item at index `1 + 2*(not 1%2)-1` or `1 + 2*(not 1)-1` or `1 + 2*0-1` or `0`.

2 would grab the item at index `2 + 2*(not 2%2)-1` or `2 + 2*(not 0)-1` or `2 + 2*1-1` or `3`.

3 would grab the item at index `3 + 2*(not 3%2)-1` or `3 + 2*(not 1)-1` or `3 + 2*0-1` or `2`.

As you can see, instead of `0123` it goes `1032`, and this pattern will continue until the result is complete.

Comment: I'm conflicted about this. On the one hand, `idx+2*(not idx%2)-1` is absurdly cryptic, relying on amusingly non-intuitive behaviors. On the other hand, I love clever code, even if it's the sort of clever the author doesn't understand a week later. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Well, it's the Python code for the algorithm I wanted. I chose not to use a ternary operator, but you could use one and express the indexing as `[idx-(1 if idx%2 else -1)]` or `[idx-1 if idx%2 else idx+1]`. If you find those clearer, I'll be happy to add them to the answer.

Comment: Nah, I wasn't criticizing, that was intended as a compliment more than anything else.