# List to Dictionary: Even items as keys, odd items as values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to use Python to convert a `list` into a `dictionary` and I need to help coming up with a simple solution.  The list that I would like to convert looks like this:

```
inv = ['apples', 2, 'oranges', 3, 'limes', 10, 'bananas', 7, 'grapes', 4]
```

I want to create a `dictionary` from this `list`, where the items in the even positions (apples, oranges, limes, bananas, grapes) are the `keys`, and the items in the odd positions (2, 3, 10, 7, 4) are the `values`.

```
inv_dict = {'apples':2, 'oranges':3, 'limes':10, 'bananas':7, 'grapes':4}
```

I've tried using something like `enumerate` to count the position of the item, and then if it's even, set it as a `key`.  But then I'm not sure how to match the following number up with it's correct item.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Shortest way:

```
dict(zip(inv[::2], inv[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `zip`:

```
dict([(x, y) for x, y in zip(inv[::2], inv[1::2])])
# {'apples': 2, 'bananas': 7, 'grapes': 4, 'limes': 10, 'oranges': 3}
```

Or as @DSM suggested:

```
dict(zip(inv[::2], inv[1::2]))
# {'apples': 2, 'bananas': 7, 'grapes': 4, 'limes': 10, 'oranges': 3}
```

Comment: There's no need for the list comprehension here; `dict(zip(inv..))` would work equally well.

Comment: @DSM Nice a even short answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the [*pairwise iteration*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5389507/771848) and call [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor on the resulting list of pairs, which would create a dictionary using first items as keys and second as values:

> Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
> objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
> dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

Sample:

```
>>> inv = ['apples', 2, 'oranges', 3, 'limes', 10, 'bananas', 7, 'grapes', 4]
>>> dict(pairwise(inv))
{'grapes': 4, 'bananas': 7, 'apples': 2, 'oranges': 3, 'limes': 10}
```

where `pairwise()` function is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/771848):

```
from itertools import izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a)
```

Python3 version:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)
```

Comment: Another use of your iterable: ` a = iter(inv); {i:next(a) for i in a}`