# turning a list into pairs and writing them to a .db file with sqlite3

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I need to take a list of information such as:

```
my_list = ['a','1','b','2','c','3','d','4']
```

I need to write this information as pairs into two separate columns in a .db file with sqlite3.

```
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
```

sqlite3 will not allow me to pass a list as an argument so I tired:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('mytest.db')
cursor = conn.cursor
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(c1 TEXT, c2 TEXT)')

for i in my_list[0:len(my_list):2]:
    cursor.execute(INSERT INTO test (c1) VALUES (?)',(i,))
    connection.commit

for i in my_list[1:len(my_list):2]:
    cursor.execute(INSERT INTO test (c2) VALUES (?)',(i,))
    connection.commit
```

However, this is making the table appear like so:

```
|  a   | null |
|  b   | null |
|  c   | null |
|  d   | null |
| null |  1   |
| null |  2   |
| null |  3   |
| null |  4   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [pairwise iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5389507/771848) and `executemany()`:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

my_list = ['a','1','b','2','c','3','d','4']
cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        test (c1, c2) 
    VALUES 
        (?, ?)""", pairwise(my_list))
connection.commit()  # note: you need to call the commit method
```

Comment: `literator = iter(my_list)` and `zip(literator, literator)` would be more efficient with space

Comment: @inspectorG4dget you are right, just wanted to demonstrate the idea..thanks!

Comment: I am confused what the difference is with inspectors code.