# List of datetimes with the context of working hours, calculate non working hours

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, optimization, python-datetime

So I have a set of working times (shifts), i.e. a tuple of start and end points in datetime format. One person then is able to have multiple shifts on the same day:

```py
from datetime import datetime
shift1_1 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=21, hour=8)
shift1_2 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=21, hour=11)
shift2_1 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=21, hour=12)
shift2_2 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=21, hour=17)
shift3_1 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=22, hour=8)
shift3_2 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=22, hour=10)
shift4_1 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=22, hour=12)
shift4_2 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=22, hour=15)
shift5_1 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=22, hour=17)
shift5_2 = datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=22, hour=19)
shifts = [(shift1_1,shift1_2), (shift2_1,shift2_2), (shift3_1,shift3_2), (shift4_1,shift4_2),(shift5_1,shift5_2)]
```

I would like to calculate the complement, so start and end points of non working hours.

How would one tackle this problem? As for right now, I did not find a practical method of calculation. Does anybody know an algorithm for this problem?

I would be grateful for any hint in the right direction.

Comment: What is does your desired result from the above sample data look like?

Comment: #daystart_shift1 to 3 and dayend_shif1 to 3 are the ends and starts of the equivalent days
```off_times = [ (daystart_shift1, shift1_1), (shift1_2, dayend_shift2), (daystart_shift2, shift2_1), (shift2_2, dayend_shift2), (daystart_shift3, shift3_1), (shift3_2, shift4_1), (shift4_2, shift5_1), (shift5_2, daysend_shift3)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of the post of [tituszban](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57590903/876847)

I generate a list of days I have in my list of shifts. Then I loop over all my shifts and split them up into a list of single datetimes.
For each day I then:

- create an empty list
- create one datetime object each for beginning and end of the given day
- add beginning of the day
- filter my list of single datetimes of shifts to match given day and loop over this filter, adding the datetimes to my list
- using [pairwise iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/876847) I can create new tuples and add them to off_times list

In the end I get a new array of tuples containing my off_times.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```py
off_times = []
for i in range(shifts - 1):
   off_times.append((shifts[i][1], shifts[i + 1][0]))
```

Comment: I will try this, looks promising