# Function applied to the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas, loops, distance

Manually defined *p* and *q*:

```
p = [[45.1024,7.7498],[45.1027,7.7513],[45.1072,7.7568],[45.1076,7.7563]]
q = [[45.0595,7.6829],[45.0595,7.6829],[45.0564,7.6820],[45.0533,7.6796],[45.0501,7.6775]]
```

- Step 1 (fine)

Part of code which is fine

```
def _c(ca, i, j, p, q):
    if ca[i, j] > -1:
        return ca[i, j]
    elif i == 0 and j == 0:
        ca[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j])
    elif i > 0 and j == 0:
        ca[i, j] = max(_c(ca, i-1, 0, p, q), np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j]))
    elif i == 0 and j > 0:
        ca[i, j] = max(_c(ca, 0, j-1, p, q), np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j]))
    elif i > 0 and j > 0:
        ca[i, j] = max(
            min(
                _c(ca, i-1, j, p, q),
                _c(ca, i-1, j-1, p, q),
                _c(ca, i, j-1, p, q)
            ),
            np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j])
            )
    else:
        ca[i, j] = float('inf')
    return ca[i, j]
```

- Step 2(problem is here) is

```
def frdist(p, q):

    # Remove nan values from p
    p = np.array([i for i in p if np.any(np.isfinite(i))], np.float64) # ESSENTIAL PART TO REMOVE NaN
    q = np.array([i for i in q if np.any(np.isfinite(i))], np.float64) # ESSENTIAL PART TO REMOVE NaN

    len_p = len(p)
    len_q = len(q)

    if len_p == 0 or len_q == 0:
        raise ValueError('Input curves are empty.')

    # p and q no longer have to be the same length
    if len(p[0]) != len(q[0]):
        raise ValueError('Input curves do not have the same dimensions.')

    ca = (np.ones((len_p, len_q), dtype=np.float64) * -1)

    dist = _c(ca, len_p-1, len_q-1, p, q)
    return(dist)
```

```
frdist(p, q)
0.09754839824415232
```

Question:
What to do in **Step 2** to apply the code to the given  (again sample dataset. The real one is very big)dataset df:

```
    1           1.1     2           2.1     3           3.1     4           4.1     5           5.1
0   43.1024     6.7498  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
1   46.0595     1.6829  25.0695     3.7463  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
2   25.0695     5.5454  44.9727     8.6660  41.9726     2.6666  84.9566     3.8484  44.9566     1.8484
3   35.0281     7.7525  45.0322     3.7465  14.0369     3.7463  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
4   35.0292     7.5616  45.0292     4.5616  23.0292     3.5616  45.0292     6.7463  NaN
```

By taking p first row and q second row. Then compute the distance `frdist(p, q)`. Then again p is the first row but q now third row. Then 1 and 3.

Finally I should get the matrix in the size of rows (rows, rows) with 0 diagonal. Because distance between itself is 0:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 105
0 0
1   0
2     0
3       0  
4         0
5           0
...           0
105              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your working code expects list of lists as argument, you need to convert each row of your dataframe to a list of lists like the `p` and `q` of your example. Assuming `df` is your dataframe, you can do this in the following way:

```
def pairwise(it):
    a = iter(it)
    return zip(a, a)

ddf = df.apply(lambda x : [pair for pair in pairwise(x)], axis=1)
```

I took the `pairwise` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/10426037).

`ddf` is a dataframe with one column, each element is a list like `p` or `q`.

Then you need to work with combinations of the row indexes. Have a look at the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. Depending on your needs, you can use one from [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) or [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

If you want to do each combination, you can use:

```
from itertools import product
idxpairs = product(ddf.index, repeat=2)
```

`idxpairs` holds all possible pairs of the indexes in your dataframe. You can loop over them.

You can build your final matrix like this:

```
fmatrix = pd.DataFrame(index=ddf.index, columns=ddf.index)

for pp in idxpairs:
    fmatrix.loc[pp[0], pp[1]] = frdist(ddf.iloc[pp[0]], ddf.iloc[pp[1]])
```

Now this will compute brute force each element. If you have a big dataframe and you know in advance that your final matrix will have given properties, like the diagonal is 0 and it is symmetric (I guess `frdist(p, q) == frdist(q, p)`) you can save some time by using for example `combinations` instead of `product` to not perform the same calculations twice:

```
from itertools import combinations
idxpairs = combinations(ddf.index, 2)

fmatrix = pd.DataFrame(index=ddf.index, columns=ddf.index)

for pp in idxpairs:
    res = frdist(ddf.iloc[pp[0]], ddf.iloc[pp[1]])
    fmatrix.loc[pp[0], pp[1]] = res
    fmatrix.loc[pp[1], pp[0]] = res
```

Comment: One amendment: ''itertoos'' supposed to be ''itertools'', yes?

Comment: Everything works. But one question: As you can see in my p and q sample `frdist` is `0.09754839824415232`. Nut when I am applying your code in real daatset, where my first 2 rows are the numbers of p and q I have illustrated here, my frdist is `0.0879574`.

Comment: Yes, `itertoos` is a typo. Fixed

Comment: @Mamed about the different results, I don't know. Check that the numbers are really the same: I've tested, and I get the same result by using both `frdist` directly and my solution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Iw works Now I need do deal with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: Your `_c` function is recursive, it comes from there.