# Scrapy: Selector for text between two HTML elements..?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am currently using scrapy to scrape a website. The Website is a list of profiles. So the Spider click on every link in the list (which is one profile) and then extract the data, comes back and clicks on the next one etc. This is how I structured it:

```
class Profiles(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'profiles'
    allowed_domains = ['url.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.url/profiles/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for profile in response.css('.herald-entry-content p'):
            url = response.urljoin(profile.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first())
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_profile, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_profile(self, response):
        birth_name = response.xpath("//*[@id='post-19807']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/text()[1]").extract()
        profile = Profile(
            birth_name=birth_name
        )
        yield profile
```

While working, I have encountered a problem with fetching certain data. Here is a snippet of what the structure looks like on the actual profile page:

```
    <div class="herald-entry-content">
        <p><b>Profile: Facts<br>
        </b><br>
            <span>Stage Name:</span> Any name<br>
            <span>Birth Name:</span> Any name<br>
            <span>Birthday:</span> July 10, 1994<br>
            <span>Zodiac Sign:</span> Cancer<br>
            <span>Height:</span> 178 cm <br>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I would like to extract the `Birth Name` here, but using `birth_name = response.css(".herald-entry-content p span::Text")` will give me the text of the span element, which is not what i want. I tried playing around with xpath (right click and Copy Xpath in chrome) which gave me `//*[@id="post-19807"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/text()[2]`
Now, this works, but the `post-id` is specific to this page, and I do loop over the other profiles as well, so that value will change a lot. Is there any way I can tell the spider to look for the element and get the ID itself? Im kind of lost how to proceed with this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you share the html with `post-id`.

Comment: @supputuri : here u go, i removed all the scripts etc.. https://jsfiddle.net/hz9pycde/

Comment: Not sure why you want to relay on the `post-xxxxx`. You can get the `birth_name` using simple `//article//p[1]/text()[4]`. This should work on all the posts, though loop through them.

Comment: @supputuri: That sadly looks wrong, I do get it for some of the pages, but for 95% it puts wrong text, or an "new line (slash n)" e.g ```{"birth_name": ["\n"]},
{"birth_name": ["\n"]},
{"birth_name": [" January 30, 1989", "\n"]},
{"birth_name": [" Bae Soo Bin (\ubc30\uc218\ube48)", "\n"]},```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a case that you have to fallback to a regular expression.

Without knowing the full structure of the page it is hard to give you exactly what you need, but here is an example using the snippet you gave

```py
import scrapy

sel = scrapy.Selector(text="""
 <div class="herald-entry-content">
        <p><b>Profile: Facts<br>
        </b><br>
            <span>Stage Name:</span> Any name<br>
            <span>Birth Name:</span> Any name<br>
            <span>Birthday:</span> July 10, 1994<br>
            <span>Zodiac Sign:</span> Cancer<br>
            <span>Height:</span> 178 cm <br>
        </p>
    </div>
""")

info = sel.re("<span>(.+):</span>\s(.+)<br>")
output = dict(zip(*[iter(info)] * 2))
print(output)
```

will give you

```
{'Stage Name': 'Any name', 
 'Birth Name': 'Any name', 
 'Birthday': 'July 10, 1994', 
 'Zodiac Sign': 'Cancer', 
 'Height': '178 cm '}
```

The slightly cryptic `dict(zip(*[iter(info)] * 2))` comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/11946287).

Note you shouldn't have to use the `scrapy.Selector` directly, you should be able to do something like

```
def parse_profile(self, response):
    herald_content = response.xpath('//div[@class="herald-entry-content"]')
    info = herald_content.re("<span>(.+):</span>\s(.+)<br>")
    # and so on from example above...
```

Comment: @tomjin I have included the HTML, if that helps. But I will look at your solution tomorrow. Thanks a lot! https://jsfiddle.net/hz9pycde/

Comment: Nice use of re I would have just gotten the text of div.herald-entry-content and then cleaned it and zipped it. The regular expression probably eliminates the need for cleaning up white space.