# Finding particular outcomes of sub-lists

Tags: python

I'm attempting to find a way for a given list to convert into multiple sub lists.

This works, however, the next thing I want is for the lists to only output when they are adjacent to one another. for example right now `['a','b','c']` outputs:

`[],['a'],['b'],['c'],['a', 'b'],['a','c']` etc, I don't want `['a','c']` as they should not go next to each other. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
def list_thing(theList):
    initial = []
    lists = [initial]
    for i in range(len(theList)):
        original = lists[:]
        new = theList[i]
        for j in range(len(output)):
            lists[j] = lists[j] + [new]
        lists = lists + output
    return lists
```

edit: To clarify, as I have been asked, I would also like `['a','b','c']` as they are a possible result.

Just to explain further `['a','b','c','d']` would give combos like `['a','b'], ['b','c'],['c','d'], ['a','b','c','d']` These would be acceptable answers.

While `['a','b','c'] ['a','c']` would not as they are not individually next to each other or part of the larger string.

Comment: What about `['a','b','c']` itself? If not, because you do not want the list itself, or because you want only lists with at most two elements?

Comment: What do you mean by they should not go next to each other? Is it because a and c are not continuous in the alphabet?

Comment: Sounds like that you just want to take a slice the list. Now try to compute all the possible start/end indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this achieves what you're after:

```
>>> def lister(some_list):
...   result = [[]]
...   result.extend([i] for i in some_list)
...   result.extend(map(list, zip(some_list, some_list[1:])))
...   result.append(some_list)
...   return result
... 
>>> lister(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
[[], ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: This is almost there, but need it to be in square brackets, do you have a link where you learnt how to do this or was it experience?

Comment: You can learn more about pairwise iteration here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list.  It's not exactly what you asked for, because you also need individual elements, but it's an abstraction of the 3rd line in the function I wrote here.  Changing to square brackets (lists) instead of parenthesis (tuples) is just mapping `list` over the results of `zip`.