# How can I iterate a list with repeated values?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem in my code where I'm trying to check if (in my case) there is a review already created with that title from that reviewer.

For that I'm doing:

```
def review_result(self):
    print("Complete your review")
    title = input("Title of the paper: ")
    reviewer = input("Reviewer's name: ")
    for x in self.__review:
        if x == title:
            index = self.__review.index(x)
            if self.__review[index + 1] == reviewer:
```

But in my `self.__review` list I can have the same title repeated multiple times but all with diferent reviewers, for example: `['Book1', 'Rev1', 'Book1', 'Rev2', 'Book1' Rev3']`

When I have 2 reviews from the same paper I can't access the 2nd review because that `for x in self.__review` is only searching for the 1st value that apears.

Is there any way I can see the next 'x' in that `for x in self.__review` loop?

Comment: A different data structure would suit you better.

Comment: `for x in self.__review` is iterating over the entire list. The problem is, as @TomServo pointed out, you've chosen the wrong data structure. Not knowing what your ultimate goal is, I would suggest trying a dict where the keys are the books and the values are a list of reviews. For your data, it would look like `{"Book1": ["Rev1", "Rev2", "Rev3"]}`

Comment: Do you have identical reviews? If not, you could go the other way `{"rev1":"book1", "rev2":"book1"}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over every two elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try to do a dict as you told, that might work for my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`:

```py
for index, x in enumerate(self.__review):
    current_review = x
    next_review = self.__review[index + 1] # note that this will error when you reach the last item on the list, make sure you have handling for it!
    # more code
```