# Python joining an array into a single line with a new line for every two elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an array with 8 items like the below array (dummy data), I only want the first 6 items. I can't seem to get .join correct.

```
["MR_L: ", 20, "Time: ", "10:00", "Email: ", "Testing@test", "Telephone: ", 0002411212]
```

I want the out come to be in a string:

```
"MR_L: 20
Time: 10:00
Email: Testing@test"
```

I've tried a for loop like: `for index in range (0, 5, 2)` then use index `-1`. It is important this is all in one string as I am using a function that can only take a single string as an argument. When I use join I get a memory error.

Comment: How big is the array actually (or rather the items in it)?

Comment: The longest the array will be is 22 items, it will join 18 and ignore the final two pairs. The name field can be 34 characters long as a string, the biggest integer is 16 digits long.

Comment: That's not a valid Python list due to the leading zeroes for the last value. Also... "memory error"?

Comment: Okay, so it's not gigabytes in size. Can you please show the exact and complete error message with traceback?

Comment: `8 - 6 = 2`, `22 - 18 = 4`. So what's your rule of changing ratio?

Comment: File "c:\Users\red\OneDrive - ---\---\---\---\app.py", line 150, in Get_Da
    outPut = outPut.join(allItems[i-1] + allItems[i] + "\n")
MemoryError

Comment: 2 items : 1 new line

Comment: @OttoLuck This is a guess but if your value in *i* is massive then I suppose that *might* induce a memory error. Unfortunately you've chosen not to share your code so its hard to tell

Comment: So is your question how you can resolve the memory error or if your code was correct if you did not get a memory error?

Comment: I guess it was both, both where resolved thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the integer value(s) in your list are valid then you could do this:

```
mylist = ["MR_L: ", 20, "Time: ", "10:00", "Email: ", "Testing@test", "Telephone: ", 2411212]

parts = []

for i in range(0, min(6, len(mylist)), 2):
    parts.append('{}{}'.format(*mylist[i:i+2]))

print(*parts, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
MR_L: 20
Time: 10:00
Email: Testing@test
```

Comment: I tried this although instead of print used: outPut = outPut + ('\n'.join(parts)).

It repeats data constantly?

Comment: @OttoLuck Why don't you try it in the way I've written it then ask yourself why, when you change the code, it goes wrong

Comment: This worked with the original edit for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do it. One way is like this:

```py
data = ["MR_L: ", 20, "Time: ", "10:00", "Email: ", "Testing@test", "Telephone: ", 2411212]

# STEP 1. convert all items to str type and put \n (newline) to every second items.
str_data = [str(item) if i % 2 == 0 else str(item)+"\n" for i, item in enumerate(data)]
print(str_data)
# ['MR_L: ', '20\n', 'Time: ', '10:00\n', 'Email: ', 'Testing@test\n', 'Telephone: ', '2411212\n']

# STEP 2. combine the first six items 
result = "".join(str_data[:6])[:-1] # [:-1] to remove last "\n"
print(result)
"""
MR_L: 20
Time: 10:00
Email: Testing@test
"""
```

Comment: This just saves 3 items of the 18 that I want

Comment: @OttoLuck 18? I quote from your question "I only want the first 6 items"

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `pairwise()` implementation from [Iterating over every two elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/78845) to solve that part of your problem.

Next you can convert your pairs into strings:

```
[f"{k}{v}" for k, v in pairwise(allItems)]
```

Omit the last pair (two elements):

```
[f"{k}{v}" for k, v in pairwise(allItems[:-2])]
```

And join with newlines:

```
"\n".join(f"{k}{v}" for k, v in pairwise(allItems[:-2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your data suggests a pairwise grouping:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

data = ["MR_L: ", 20, "Time: ", "10:00", "Email: ", "Testing@test", "Telephone: ", 2411212]

# group in pairs [["MR_L: ", 20], ...]
pairs = pairwise(data) # returns an iterable

# you then join pairs (you need 3 pairs for 6 items)
"\n".join(f"{k}{v}" for k, v in list(pairs)[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using generator expression and `zip` of the list from index 0 to length of the list -2 with 2 step and from index 1 likewise:

```
mylist = ["MR_L: ", 20, "Time: ", "10:00", "Email: ", "Testing@test", "Telephone: ", 2411212]

outPut = lambda lst: '\n'.join(f'{a}{b}' for a,b in zip(lst[:-2:2],lst[1::2]))

print(outPut(mylist))

# MR_L: 20
# Time: 10:00
# Email: Testing@test
```