# How loop with Python and increment XML tree

Tags: python, xml

I have this code:

```
linenum = 1
for g in u.answers:
    attr = ""
    lines.append("\t\t<answer%s>%s</answer>" % (attr, g[0]))
    linenum += 1
```

which results in:

```
<xml>
    <answer>Primary Job Function</answer>
    <answer>Engineering</answer>
    <answer>Size of Company</answer>
    <answer>100</answer>
    <answer>Job Level</answer>
    <answer>Manager</answer>
    <answer>Type of Company</answer>
    <answer>Supplier</answer>
<xml>
```

Would like to increment and get the following result:

```
<xml>
    <question1>Primary Job Function</question1>
    <answer1>Engineering</answer1>
    <question2>Size of Company</question2>
    <answer2>100</answer2>
    <question3>Job Level</question3>
    <answer3>Manager</answer3>
    <question4>Type of Company</question4>
    <answer4>Supplier</answer4>
</xml>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask].  Even the partial code shown wouldn't result in the example output.

Answer (score 0):

`attr` is assigned to an empty string and never changes. Also the canonical way to count in `for` loops is to use `enumerate` and `%` is a very old method for formatting strings. Try this:

```
for i, g in enumerate(zip(u.answers[::2], u.answers[1::2])):
    linenum = i + 1
    lines.append(f"\t\t<question{linenum}>{g[0]}</question{linenum}>")
    lines.append(f"\t\t<answer{linenum}>{g[1]}</answer{linenum}>")
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list) on how to use `zip` or `pairwise` to iterate over pairs in a list.

Comment: Thanks for the info..   Tried your solution but it does not resovle...

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not resolve"? What didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

End up with this approach....

```
    for i in range (len (u.answers)):
        attr = ""
        if (i%2 == 0):
            lines.append("\t\t<question{0}>{1}</question{0}>".format(i+1, u.answers[i][0]))


    for i in range (len (u.answers)):
        attr = ""
        if (i%2 != 0):
            lines.append("\t\t<answer{0}>{1}</answer{0}>".format(i, u.answers[i][0]))
```