# Subtract Consective Numbers in Array in Python

Tags: python

I want to subtract consecutive numbers in an array `a`:

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 2]
```

The resulting array should be:

```
res = [2, 3, 7]
```

So I want to subtract 1-3, 4-7 and then 9-2 in Python and get the absolute value. How can I make a code or function to do this?

I tried doing

```
res = a[0:] - a[:+1]
```

but this gives me

```
res = [-2, -3, -6, -8, -1]
```

Comment: Use `abs` for absolute value if you don't want the negative signs.

Comment: What made you think `res= a[0:]-a[:+1]` would do anything remotely close to what you want to do? And no it would not give you `res = [-2, -3, -6, -8, -1]` at all either. Please put some actual effort into it, especially since this looks like your homework.

Comment: `res = [x - y for x, y in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]`. I left out one small part because I don't want to do all the homework for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over every two elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most efficient way to subtract consecutive array elements using `zip()`

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 2]
res = [abs(y-x) for x,y in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: This is definitely the most readable and pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`abs` for absolute value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) if you don't want the negative signs;
- Use [`a[i:i+2]` to get an array of length 2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) starting at index `i`;
- Use [`range(0, len(a), 2)` to have values of `i` that increment by 2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

```py
def subtractions_by_pairs(a):
    res = []
    for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
        x, y = a[i:i+2]
        res.append(abs(y-x))
    return res

print(subtractions_by_pairs([1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 2]))
# [2, 3, 7]
```

Or using `zip` to combine two sequences, and using `a[::2]` and `a[1::2]` to get the subsequences of element at even indices and odd indices:

```py
def subtractions_by_pairs(a):
    assert(len(a) % 2 == 0)
    return [abs(y - x) for x, y in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]
```

Comment: And with `zip`: `[abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]`

Comment: Which will crash with `ValueError` if the list has an odd length.

Comment: @JorgeLuis Yes. That's on purpose. What behaviour would you expect instead of a ValueError? A custom LengthError exception?

Answer (score 0):

Those are lists, not arrays. You need to iterate over the indices, but you only really need *every other* index starting with zero.

This is readily implemented using a list comprehension.

```
[
  abs(a[i] - a[i+1]) 
  for i in range(0, len(a) - 1, 2)
]
```

Result:

```
[2, 3, 7]
```

By subtracting `1` from the length in the call to `range`, we can prevent an error when `a` is of uneven length.

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9]
>>> [
...   abs(a[i] - a[i+1]) 
...   for i in range(0, len(a) - 1, 2)
... ]
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 2]

# using slicing
res = [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]

# or with an iterator
i = iter(a)
res = [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(i, i)]
```

Output: `[2, 3, 7]`

If you want to perform more complex operations, you should maybe use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), which allows you to perform vectorial operations similarly to what you were trying to do with `res= a[0:]-a[:+1]`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 2])

res = abs(a[::2] - a[1::2])
```

Output: `array([2, 3, 7])`

Answer (score 0):

Lemme add some functional kung-fu with the benefit of introducing some useful libraries and concepts:

```
from operator import sub

[*map(abs, map(sub, i:=iter(a), i))]
# [2, 3, 7]
```

Some docs:

- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)
- [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)
- [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub)
- [walrus operator `:=`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub)

Comment: And in Python 3.12 we´ll be able to do: `[*map(abs, starmap(sub, batched(a, 2)))]`

Comment: Those will be the days =)

Comment: Alternatively: `d = lambda x,y: abs(x-y)); i = iter(a); list(map(d, i, i))`. In general, there is no need to combine `zip` and `starmap`: you can use `map` directly with more than one sequence.

Comment: @Stef That is indeed a simplification. Fixed it while avoiding the ugly lambda. The double map kinda emphasizes the function chaining.