# Get Pairs of List Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for a,b in func(c):
    doSomething()
```

So func() have to return `(1,2) (2,3) (3,4) ... (8,9) (9,10)`

Is there a elegant method in python 2.7 to achieve this?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631222/3001761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, there are many ways.  Simplest:

```
def func(alist):
    return zip(alist, alist[1:])
```

This spends a lot of memory in Python 2, since `zip` makes an actual list and so does the slicing.  There are several alternatives focused on generators that offer memory savings, such as a very simple:

```
def func(alist):
    it = iter(alist)
    old = next(it, None)
    for new in it:
        yield old, new
        old = new
```

Or you can get fancier deploying the powerful `itertools` instead, as in the `pairwise` recipe proposed by @HughBothwell .

Comment: how does this zip solution actually work?

Answer (score 5):

The [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) has a recipe for this:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

then

```
for a,b in pairwise(c):
    doSomething(a, b)
```

Comment: why use python code while built-in `zip`  could do that with `C`?

Comment: @KasraAD: two main circumstances: one, if you are working on a very long list (`zip[:1]` makes a second copy of the list to iterate over); two, if you are working from a generator (`tee` uses a deque to store each value the first time it is requested). For short lists the `zip(c, c[:1])` approach is entirely suitable.

Comment: yes im agree . and i just mean for this case ;) .

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> list(zip(a,a[1:]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
```

The other ways are

- `[(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]`

As you wanter a function you can do

```
func = lambda a : list(zip(a,a[1:]))
```

Comment: You don't need the `a[::1]` just `a` and `a[1:]` will work

Comment: Hope all is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> def pair(sample_list):
...    return zip(sample_list,sample_list[1:])
... 
>>> pair(a)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
```

Or with `iter()` that return an iterator , so you can use `next()` attribute of iterator in a list comprehension to get the proper pairs , note that in both recipes the second object need to be slice from first element to end `[1:]` ,  and i following you need to slice the main list from leading to end except the last element , because the iterator will chose it :

```
>>> def pair(sample_list):
...    it_a=iter(sample_list[1:])
...    return [(i,it_a.next()) for i in sample_list[:-1]]
... 
>>> pair(a)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c = list(range(1, 11))
for a, b in zip(c[:-1], c[1:]):
    doSomething()
```

Comment: Using `c[:-1]` is wasteful; it makes an entire copy of the last in order to exclude the last element which `zip` would have stopped before anyway.